# Xcode 8 Console Garbage?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

Has anybody else had issues with the Xcode 8 console showing a bunch of random stuff?  I don't want to have all of this cluttering my debug messages and logs.  Does anybody know how to turn this off?

EDIT: The release notes specify that the console might dump unhelpful stuff for watchOS, but not for iOS.

Example: [image: example of garbage in console]

Comment: You're aware that Xcode 8 is a Beta version right, as well as the latest SDKs?

Comment: Yes, I am.  But why should that make a difference?

Comment: If you want to use beta versions of apps don't expect them to perform like release versions.

Comment: Did you turn off the Dynamic linker API usage in xcode ?

Comment: My temporary work-around is to prepend *** to my logs and then filter by ***. Hopefully they'll fix it in the next beta.

Comment: @ellman121 pls refer to my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-xcode-8-logs/38267793#38267793

Comment: I've posted the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-xcode-8-logs/39461256#39461256

Comment: It still shows up in the release version... No idea what's the point or how to use it.

Comment: I cannot recall where i learned of this tool, but so far in my testing, it is *perfect* to avoid the stunning noise in the background of iOS10..

https://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/

Answer (score 221, accepted):

You can disable that output with a environment variable.

In Product>>Scheme>>Edit Scheme...>>Run add the following environment variable: Name:`OS_ACTIVITY_MODE`, Value: `disable`

Originally described on Twitter [here](https://twitter.com/rustyshelf/status/775505191160328194).

[image]

Comment: It will also disables the normal NSLog information when using a real device.

Comment: is that means that in order to disable the output with an environment variable we need do this in every project? is there any shortcut that we could do it to all projects once for all?

Comment: NSlog still works for me @Golden -  this solution is good

Comment: Same problem on my device, what should I do? @Golden

Comment: But how to disable the same on a device? I mean the logs from a real iPhone or iPad shown in Window -> Devices menu? Very often, we need to see the logs of a distribution/production app installed on a device (non-debug mode).

Comment: This has been fixed by Apple in Xcode 8.1 (on macOS Sierra) - no need for any environment variables!

Comment: @Sherwin - no offense, but one thing you learn with time is that Apple don't give a crap to developers. Just see Xcode and iTunesConnect, both a disgrace.

Comment: Flag or no flag, this does not work with my iPhone 7 Plus, iOS 10.2, Xcode 8.2. Getting lots of "AppleBiometricSensor" crap.

Comment: This is not a good answer despite so many people upvoted it and has a green tick. NSLog gets filtered as well if you use this method.

Comment: Not works for real devices

Comment: Still getting logs in 8.2, I'm on El Capitan

Comment: This solution will hide all NSLog starting with Xcode 9. To keep NSLog, replace `disable` with `default`.

Comment: You should use ASL (Apple system logger) and New console app where you can easily hide\show different log sources. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39581193/991816)

Comment: As Coeur says, replacing disable with default works to reenable NSLog to console.  But how then to filter out all the noise again?

Answer (score 2):

It seems this information is not garbage and can help with the variables view when checking system framework calls. However, this seems more related to debugging for the engineers at Apple and seems to have been logged as an xcode 8 issue. No idea when this will be resolved.

I also checked (started) the key binding with a "show" and "display" filters but none are relative to this. Below is apple's note:

• Xcode Debug Console shows extra logging from system frameworks when debugging applications in the Simulator. (27331147, 26652255).

Comment: Meanwhile filter by a a tag, in Swift, you can modify print:


`public func print(items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    let output = items.map { "*\($0)" }.joinWithSeparator(separator)
    Swift.print("YOUR_TAG:" + output, terminator: terminator)
}
`

Comment: @MartinRomañuk - where/how are you doing this modification?

Comment: Just add an extension.swift with the previous content inside.
Edit: You can drop it in any place of your code

Comment: Still an issue in Xcode 10.  :-(