# Xcode 8 iOS 10 non stop device logs

Tags: xcode, ios10

My Xcode 8 device log from an iOS 10 iPhone 6s+ is printing the following lines non continuously and I can't stop it or don't know a way to stop it. Any way I can stop these from printing?

```
Sep 20 14:34:41 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: Status={0x80, 0x20, 00, 0x10, 00, 00, 00, 0x11, 0x1, 0x1, 00, 0x4, 0xf0, 0x2, 0x9, 00}
Sep 20 14:34:41 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: Sent message of 20 bytes
Sep 20 14:34:41 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: exit, err=0x0
Sep 20 14:34:41 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: mask=0xFF, bad=false
Sep 20 14:34:41 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: exit
Sep 20 14:34:41 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: entry
Sep 20 14:34:41 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: exit
Sep 20 14:34:42 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: entry
Sep 20 14:34:42 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: entry
Sep 20 14:34:42 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: txBufferLength=7 rxBufferLength=23
Sep 20 14:34:42 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>: Wrote:     7B | 0x80 0x10 0x00 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x00
Sep 20 14:34:42 iPhone kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] <Debug>:  Read:    23B | 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x20 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x11
```

PS: I tried disabling touch id but no luck.

Also, I am not talking about console logs. I am talking about the device logs.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8 Console Garbage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930506/xcode-8-console-garbage)

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of that one - this one is specific to all device logs...not just a single application log.  I also am seeing it when loading the device log.

Comment: I have just noticed this happening on my device when I tried looking for app-specific logs for debugging. This might be why my device's battery is so poor right now! I am filtering to see the AppleBiometricSensor logs, but the full stream is massive. And it repeats approximate every second!!

Comment: This is OP here. Does anyone know how to create a bug with Apple for this. Would that require a paid developer account?

Comment: Note: I've submitted an Apple bug report about this, and they closed it as a duplicate: `Duplicate of 28421825 (Closed)`. The "closed" means that the thing mine is a duplicate of is also closed. But, not fixed. Unbelievable, Apple.

Answer (score 21):

Upgrade to macOS Sierra and use the re-designed Console app. It now lists connected devices and allows advanced filtering and searching of the device logs, better than anything Xcode has been able to achieve in the past, e.g. by process name as shown in the screenshot below:[image: iPhone log filtered by process]

[image]

Note: this new app unfortunately uses 30% CPU while open, hopefully Apple can fix that, in the meantime be sure to quit it when mobile or endure serious battery drain.

Comment: I do not see the drop-down menu in the search bar of my Console app (Version 1.0 (1.7.4)). Is there some menu option I need to activate to turn it on?

Comment: you have to type a search entry then press enter and the text changes into a dropdown

Comment: Awesome! It really works and it is quite reliable! Thank you so much for sharing that

Answer (score 7):

This is just a workaround.
You can try using [iOS Console](https://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/) which allows you to filter the content.

Comment: @nitinsh99 you can apply search filter (e.g your app name) here to see only your app logs . I know its now a perfect solution but until apple fix this issue you can use as workaround .

Comment: @Nanda iOS Console doesn't work.It shows same logs as Xcode. You can also apply filter in the same way in Xcode.

Comment: @Nanda Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Just a wild suggestion. Can this be fixed using a Xcode extension?

Comment: iOS Logs works perfectly for my needs - printing NSLog messages while app is in the background - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This issue depends NOT on xcode 8 it's also on xcode 7.
The "kernel(AppleBiometricSensor)[0] :" messages will gone if you put the iOS device to sleep and back again if you press home.

iOS 10.0.2 Update -> NO FIX

Comment: ios `10.0.2` does not appear to fix this. :/

Comment: This surely makes debugging an app via the devices window more challenging, holy crap. I do not use biometrics at all on my i6 and yet it is non-stop streaming.

Answer (score -1):

Device log only allow NSlog. Please could you try nslog instead print.