# Should my projects always have output in Console in Xcode 8

Tags: console, swift3, xcode8

I'm fairly new to Xcode, Swift, and making apps. So when Xcode 8 and Swift 3 came out, this was my first time having to transition my app to a new version of either.

What I'm seeing is now, every time I run my app, it instantly outputs text in the console, something that never used to happen. I was curious if it was a problem with my app, so I made a completely new app and just ran it without making any changes. And I still got the output. Is this some new feature of Xcode? Or is there possibly something wrong with my Xcode?

This is the output I'm seeing

> 2016-09-27 10:02:06.942171 Test App[42382:2680437] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2016-09-27 10:02:06.961602 Test App[42382:2680437] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2016-09-27 10:02:07.027065 Test App[42382:2680433] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
>   2016-09-27 10:02:07.065095 Test App[42382:2680364] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2016-09-27 10:02:07.103796 Test App[42382:2680364] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0

It doesn't appear that there is any mention of an error, so I'm wondering if this is even a problem, or what exactly it is trying to tell me.

Thank you all.

Comment: Not sure why Xcode8 starting doing this, but people have found a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930506/xcode-8-console-garbage

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8 Console Garbage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930506/xcode-8-console-garbage)