# Google SDK logging twice in Xcode

Tags: ios, logging, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm getting every logged messages twice from Google services. Tested with standard Google implementation for Google Analytics. (This standard configuration code is called once - even if it does not matter anyway)

```
// Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
NSError *configureError;
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);

// Optional: configure GAI options.
GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;  // report uncaught exceptions
gai.logger.logLevel = kGAILogLevelVerbose;  // remove before app release
```

Log:

```
2016-10-23 22:06:22.354166 [692:208692] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2016-10-23 22:06:22.354 [692] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2016-10-23 22:06:22.374475 [692:208692] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3404000 started
2016-10-23 22:06:22.374 [692:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3404000 started
...
```

How come?

Comment: It's not logging twice. It stores data locally and if the server responds lately then it shows the local data. Try putting a *sleep* before getting a respond from the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a case of Xcode 8 being extra verbose. I've seen this happen with Xcode 8 running with an actual device (instead of just the simulator).

I'm pretty sure if you enable the `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable` environment variable (as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930506/xcode-8-console-garbage)), this double-logging should go away.

But to be clear, this is just a case of Xcode printing out extra stuff to the console. Firebase analytics itself isn't logging twice the events that it normally does.

Comment: Nice catch. I had to set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable` though.