# Duplicate out via Firebase in my console

Tags: swift, firebase, console, firebase-analytics

I had to migrate my app recently, copied and paste a whole bunch of code. Now when I build my project I get the usual firebase output in my console except this time it is duplicated. Does anyone know what may cause this. Too much code for me to go through

```
2017-06-26 14:27:09.831490-0400 NewsFeedtt[7493:4048532] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at 
2017-06-26 14:27:09.832 NewsFeedtt[7493] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at 
2017-06-26 14:27:09.837580-0400 NewsFeedtt[7493:4048532] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.4001000 started
2017-06-26 14:27:09.838 NewsFeedtt[7493] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.4001000 started
2017-06-26 14:27:09.838733-0400 NewsFeedtt[7493:4048532]
```

Comment: You would have to give far more information than that for anyone to possibly know how to fix your problem. Also there's significantly better ways to migrate versus copy and paste.

Comment: It seems like an XCode issue. You can use the flag discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930506/xcode-8-console-garbage to remove the duplicate logs

Comment: Thanks a mil @adbitx your answer worked. And it is back to normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by @adbitx in comments