# Clear Debug Logs from Xcode programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I am of getting a JSON response on clicking NEXT and BACK buttons on simulator, each time it calls a service, I am printing that JSON response using print statement

```
print(jsonResponse)
```

It keeps adding a huge data on debugger.

Is there any way by which I can clear the debugger logs before printing the new?
Something like this:

```
clearDebuggerLogs()    //clrscr() in C

print(jsonResponse)
```

Comment: Follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930506/xcode-8-console-garbage

Comment: @PaulMarshal this one disables the normal logs also while using a real device

Comment: A simple way without adding or removing anything is to set a breakpoint on `print(jsonResponse)`. When the application hits the breakpoint, press `clear the console` button (trash bin icon) which will clear out the console and then resume the application

Comment: @Malik is right.

Comment: @Malik @PaulMarshal this is what I'm doing now, however this process is irritating when I have to do it frequently. It was pretty easy in C language, just `clrscr()` and done!

Comment: I suppose you can do something like `(1...50).forEach({ _ in print() })`. Basically adding empty lines which is a very crude way of doing it.