# Xcode 8 beta has all kinds of useless info in the debug console

Tags: xcode

Whenever I run my app, I get a bunch of lines in the debugger window like this:

```
2016-06-22 05:05:59.760494 MyProject[37892:4328438] bundleid: com.mycompany.myproject, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
```

What is this stuff? Can I get rid of it so that I have a clear console when I run my app?

Comment: Consider that it's a **beta** version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-xcode-8-logs

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a call to NSLog(). Set a symbolic breakpoint on NSLog and see who is calling NSLog as a way to check.

Answer (score 1):

The extra output is still there in the final release. I know it was raised as a radar early on in the betas. Sadly with betas many assume it is so obvious to apple as it happens to everyone that it will be fixed by the time it reaches GM.

I guess it looks like release for their keynote deadline is more important than fixing bugs. I couldn't see apple getting away with it on any other of their software but seem to think its ok when its just us developers.

```
As a temp solution:

If you run on device not simulator the output logs are fewer. A lot fewer but not completely gone.
```

Comment: I don't like to pull the "if Steve was here" card, but this shit is getting old. Maybe it's time for Tim to retire.