# requestAccessForMediaType crashing in iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, card.io, ios10, xcode8-beta2

In my app I'm using card.io to scan credit cards. It works fine in iOS 9. In iOS 10, the app is crashing and I cannot find the crash log in the xcode 8 beta 2 console as it throws a lot of garbage messages.

And then I checked in privacy->settings to see if camera is disabled for my app, but my app is not listed in that section.Seems that iOS 10 is not grnating permission for my app to use the camera.

I use the following code to request the permission:

```
-(BOOL)checkCameraPermissions{

    AVAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
        // start card-io
        return YES;
    }
    else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {

        [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted)
         {
             if(granted)
             {
                 //Start card-io
                 [self testIsNewCard];
             }

         }];
    }
    else if (authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
    {
        //Alert
        // Alert camera denied

        UIAlertController *aCon=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Camera denied" message:@"Camera cannot be used" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
            [aCon dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
        [aCon addAction:ok];
        [self presentViewController:aCon animated:YES completion:nil];

        return NO;

    }

    return NO;

}
```

When I run this code, the authStatus is returned as `AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`

and the app crashed right after it enter into the block `requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo`

There is so much of garbage logs displaying in console and I have no clue to find the crash message.

**Edit:** I found an option to disable the all the unnecessary logs in xcode 8. Answer posted [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-xcode-8-logs) But still xcode didn't showed any crash log even after disabling the backtrace debugging.

My xcode8 just shows this message and the app just quits:

```
  App[1124:226447] [access] <private>
```

I also tried resetting the location and privacy , but still the app crashes when trying to request the media access.

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, I'm still trying to figure it out

Comment: just exactly like you I do not get any crash logs!!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I added the `"Privacy - Camera Usage Description"` **key** to my info.plist file and it works now.

Comment: Strange that I added this previously and it didn't work last time but it worked now.

Comment: Awesome answer! iOS 10 requires it.

Answer (score 11):

In `iOS 10` you must declare access to any user private data types. You do this by adding a usage key to your app’s `Info.plist`. For more information please find the below screenshot for the same.

You need to add the **Privacy - Camera Usage Description** key to your app’s Info.plist and their usage information.

For more information please find the below GIF.

[image: GIF]

Or if you want to add via info.plist then you need to add **NSCameraUsageDescription** key.

Just copy and paste below string in info.plist.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Take the photo</string>
```

Please find the below GIF for more information.

[image: GIF]

For more information please review the [link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/).

Answer (score 8):

`iOS 10` has continued the privacy policy and has implemented new privacy rules. And we should remember to implement them in our next projects.

For your issue you need to add following line into `info.plist`

```
<!--  Camera -->
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>
```

Below are the rest of the privacy rules :

```
<!--  Photo Library -->
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Camera -->
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Microphone -->
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Location -->
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Location When In Use -->
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Location Always -->
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Calendars -->
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!-- ⏰ Reminders -->
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Motion -->
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Health Update -->
<key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Health Share -->
<key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!-- ᛒ Bluetooth Peripheral -->
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>

<!--  Media Library -->
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string><Your description goes here></string>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: What if multiple Use of camera? like we have QR code and also selfie taking feature. Will it enough to mention that 'this app uses Camera for multiple feature'

Comment: Yes its same as you ask for location permission you need to define once and than you can use multiple times for multiple purposes, you need to have generic description for your permissions.