# Strange Terminal Messages in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Recently, I have updated my Xcode version to 8. When I start and run an entirely new project, I get the following messages in my terminal.

```
2016-09-07 15:28:43.759998 App[7932:128675] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit,     
category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, 
default_ttl:     0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0,
enable_oversize: 1,   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-07 15:28:43.762544 App[7932:128675] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit,     
category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, 
default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0,    
enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-07 15:28:43.790817 App[7932:128648] subsystem:   
com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1,   
persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, 
generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0,  
enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-07 15:28:43.827962 App[7932:128496] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit,   
category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, 
info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, 
privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-07 15:28:43.998975 App[7932:128496] subsystem: 
com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, 
persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, 
generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0,    
enable_private_data: 0
```

Can anyone explain what these mean/why they are here?

PS: I have never gotten these types of messages with Xcode 7.

Comment: Beta versions of Xcode have extra logging

Comment: Great. I'm glad I'm not the only one!

Comment: Very related: [Hide Xcode 8 logs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37800790/2415822)

Comment: Wow. I feel dumb not seeing that. Sorry guys

Comment: This is still occurring on Xcode 8 GM unfortunately

Comment: And still occurring in the official Xcode 8 release today...

Comment: I know. I'm actually pretty pissed. It's so ugly haha

Comment: Not only that it's ugly, but it is useless too. While keeping their egos aside the XCode decision makers need to learn a lot from a real IDE like Android Studio, including how to output useful logs with useful information and also some colours.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Go to **Product => Scheme => Edit Scheme** or use shortcut: **CMD + <**

Add `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` as `disable`

[image]

And i use this answer: [hide-xcode-8-logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-xcode-8-logs) from @iDevzilla to solve this:

> Try this: On your Environment Variables set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable
>   [image]

Comment: Are you sure it won't destroy something in the project?

Comment: @AsiGivati currently I'm working on the project that I have disabled os_activity_mode and it works like a charm!

Comment: Unfortunately, this also removes any custom logging as well, nothing shows up in the console anymore.

Comment: Don't know about logging libraries, but good ol' NSLog still works with this on

Comment: OK, after some more testing: if you run your app in Simulator, this does not mute your NSLog. On device, it does.

Comment: Actually, there is nothing in Environment Variables in my xcode like OS_ACTIVITY_MODE so I still getting this crazy log. @GentBerani

Comment: @IbrahimBOLAT you have to type it out.