# Xcode 8 Simulator outputs many garbage in dubugger with "nw" prefix

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode8

When running my app through one of the simulators in Xcode 8, the log shows a lot of lines starting with this "nw" prefix.
This doesn't appear when running on real device.

Does anyone know what's the story with this? I've seen other developers complaining about this in Apple's forums, but they didn't get a corresponding reply regarding this.

Comment: This is a duplicated question, I've added the answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39461256/1496935

Comment: @iDevzilla Thanks a lot your solution works. Sorry for duplicating, i tried to search before, but couldn't find something relevant. I voted to close this question.