# Too much information being presented in Debug Area - Xcode 8

Tags: xcode

I just upgraded to Xcode 8 and upon building and running my project an enormous amount of information is being printed to the Debug Area.

Here is a sample:

016-09-14 08:37:54.394736 SmartTapp[8645:112431] subsystem: com.apple.network, category: , enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-14 08:37:54.395777 SmartTapp[8645:112431] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 1 www.smarttapp.com 80
2016-09-14 08:37:54.397472 SmartTapp[8645:112431] [] tcp_connection_start 1 starting

How do I turn this off?

I have already tried the suggestion offered here and it didn't work.[Hide strange unwanted Xcode 8 logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-xcode-8-logs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Xcode 8 logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-xcode-8-logs)

Comment: I'm afraid the information in Hide Xcode 8 logs did not work.  I've already tried that.

Comment: I've added the answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39461256/1496935

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open:

- => Product
- => Scheme
- => Edit Scheme
- => Select "Run"
- => Second Tab "Argument"
- => Inside **Environment Variables** press `+` button
- => add `Name = OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` **&** set the `Value` to `disable`
- Press `Close` button

And you are done.

[image: tcp_connection_start debug log]

Comment: Thanks! Now my XCode as clean as used to be.

Comment: Thanks! Really helped a lot!

Comment: What was OS_ACTIVITY_MODE logging? I was getting all sorts of stuff I didn't really know how to read