# Application crash immediately when deploy to iPhone running iOS10 from xCode8

Tags: objective-c, ios10, xcode8

My application can running normally on iOS9 and xCode7, but after upgrade to XCode8 and iOS10 on my iPhone, the application crash immediately after I deploy to my iPhone, before it get into the main() function.

I think there are some problems with library loading, this is the log from console when I deploy the app:

```
dyld: loaded: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/FF7E741A-6C49-424F-A8FD-9A0F49CEDAC3/iMomeetInHouse.app/iMomeetInHouse
dyld: loaded: /Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/libglInterpose.dylib
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MTLToolsDeviceSupport.framework/libMTLInterpose.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText

dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libQuadrature.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBNNS.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreBrightness.framework/CoreBrightness
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextureIO.framework/TextureIO
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libate.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/MetalPerformanceShaders
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NLP.framework/NLP
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libmarisa.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework/CoreEmoji
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleFSCompression.framework/AppleFSCompression
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlugInKit.framework/PlugInKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/CorePDF
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Frameworks/AVFAudio.framework/AVFAudio
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IntlPreferences.framework/IntlPreferences
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DCIMServices.framework/DCIMServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/CacheDelete
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserManagement.framework/UserManagement
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotosFormats.framework/PhotosFormats
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudPhotoLibrary.framework/CloudPhotoLibrary
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtectedCloudStorage.framework/ProtectedCloudStorage
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetCacheServices.framework/AssetCacheServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libheimdal-asn1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Intents.framework/Intents
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/CoreDuetDebugLogging
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudPhotoServices.framework/CloudPhotoServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CameraKit.framework/CameraKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ACTFramework.framework/ACTFramework
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AuthKit.framework/AuthKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleIDSSOAuthentication.framework/AppleIDSSOAuthentication
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleIDAuthSupport.framework/AppleIDAuthSupport
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSpotlightIndex.framework/MobileSpotlightIndex
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/IDS
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Network.framework/Network
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libAWDSupportFramework.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libprotobuf.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GLToolsCore.framework/GLToolsCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetalTools.framework/MetalTools
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MTLToolsDeviceSupport.framework/../MTLToolsDeviceSupport.framework/MTLToolsDeviceSupport
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MTLToolsDeviceSupport.framework/../GPUTools.framework/GPUTools
_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(0x18be869e8)
iMomeetInHouse(16929,0x1b1e36c40) malloc: protecting edges
iMomeetInHouse(16929,0x1b1e36c40) malloc: stack logs being written into /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7CD18EE9-0509-43EB-BA84-88C7BC509743/tmp/stack-logs.16929.102024000.iMomeetInHouse.wQKXa7.index
iMomeetInHouse(16929,0x1b1e36c40) malloc: recording malloc and VM allocation stacks to disk using standard recorder
iMomeetInHouse(16929,0x1b1e36c40) malloc: enabling scribbling to detect mods to free blocks
_dyld_get_image_slide(0x10008c000)
_dyld_get_image_slide(0x10008c000)
iMomeetInHouse(16929,0x1b1e36c40) malloc: nano zone does not support guard pages
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x18ba215f1, 1)
_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(0x18c0a1af8)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x1019a8000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x1a481f000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x101f58000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x101fc0000)
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x18c093281, 37)
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x18c0932a6, 36)
dlopen(/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib, 0x00000010)
  dlopen(/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib) ==> 0x1019feb30
dlsym(0x1019feb30, dispatch_introspection_versions)
  dlsym(0x1019feb30, dispatch_introspection_versions) ==> 0x101e13ce8
dlsym(0x1019feb30, dispatch_introspection_hooks_install)
  dlsym(0x1019feb30, dispatch_introspection_hooks_install) ==> 0x101e11710
dlsym(0x1019feb30, dispatch_get_current_queue)
  dlsym(0x1019feb30, dispatch_get_current_queue) ==> 0x101de63b4
dlsym(0x1019feb30, dispatch_queue_get_label)
  dlsym(0x1019feb30, dispatch_queue_get_label) ==> 0x101deb228
dlsym(0x1019feb30, dispatch_queue_offsets)
  dlsym(0x1019feb30, dispatch_queue_offsets) ==> 0x101e13688
dladdr(0x101e17fff, 0x16fd6f830)
dladdr(0x101e17792, 0x16fd6f830)
dladdr(0x101de51ba, 0x16fd6f830)
dladdr(0x101de516a, 0x16fd6f830)
dlclose(0x1019feb30)
dlopen(/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib, 0x00000010)
  dlopen(/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib) ==> 0x1019ffce8
dlsym(0x1019ffce8, os_unfair_lock_lock_with_options)
  dlsym(0x1019ffce8, os_unfair_lock_lock_with_options) ==> 0x18c05a510
dlsym(0x1019ffce8, os_unfair_lock_trylock)
  dlsym(0x1019ffce8, os_unfair_lock_trylock) ==> 0x18c05a540
dlsym(0x1019ffce8, os_unfair_lock_unlock)
  dlsym(0x1019ffce8, os_unfair_lock_unlock) ==> 0x18c05a570
dlclose(0x1019ffce8)
_NSGetExecutablePath(...)
_dyld_get_image_slide(0x10008c000)
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x1700f9680, 21)
dlopen(NULL, 0x00000110)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x18d9c69bc)
dlopen_preflight(/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, 0x00000115)
  dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation) ==> 0x1019fdb81
_dyld_image_count()
_dyld_get_image_header(273)
dlopen_preflight(/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES, 0x00000115)
  dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES) ==> 0x1019fcc81
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x1700f9700, 31)
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x18c092b74, 17)
_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(0x18c07ff24)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x10008c000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x1019a8000)
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x18d1fa741, 26)
dlopen_preflight(/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine, 0x00000005)
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x1a1936000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x19b90b000)
  dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine) ==> 0x1741b49e0
dlsym(0x1741b49e0, gliGetInteger)
  dlsym(0x1741b49e0, gliGetInteger) ==> 0x1a1a1a884
dlclose(0x1741b49e0)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x101a66da8)
dlopen(/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/GPUTools, 0x00000115)
  dlopen(/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/GPUTools) ==> 0x101a14ad9
_dyld_image_count()
_dyld_get_image_name(0)
_dyld_get_image_header(275)
dlopen(/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUToolsCore.framework/GPUToolsCore, 0x00000115)
  dlopen(/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUToolsCore.framework/GPUToolsCore) ==> 0x101a14431
dlopen(/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUToolsCore.framework/GPUToolsCore, 0x00000019)
  dlopen(/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUToolsCore.framework/GPUToolsCore) ==> 0x101a14430
dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYVertexPointerFilename)
  dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYVertexPointerFilename) ==> 0x101e9c988
dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYNormalPointerFilename)
  dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYNormalPointerFilename) ==> 0x101e9c998
dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYColorPointerFilename)
  dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYColorPointerFilename) ==> 0x101e9c9a0
dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYTexCoordPointerFilename)
  dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYTexCoordPointerFilename) ==> 0x101e9c990
dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYWeightPointerFilename)
  dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYWeightPointerFilename) ==> 0x101e9c9c8
dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYMatrixIndexPointerFilename)
  dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYMatrixIndexPointerFilename) ==> 0x101e9c9f0
dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYPointSizePointerFilename)
  dlsym(0x101a14430, kDYPointSizePointerFilename) ==> 0x101e9c9e8
dlclose(0x101a14430)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/SpriteKit.framework/SpriteKit, 0x00000010)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/SceneKit.framework/SceneKit, 0x00000010)
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x17408ac41, 51)
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x1740f9600, 26)
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffe, os_unfair_lock_lock)
  dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, os_unfair_lock_lock) ==> 0x18c05a39c
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x174073311, 47)
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffd, MTLUseInterpose)
  dlsym(RTLD_SELF, MTLUseInterpose) ==> 0x18f5935c4
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x1700fa300, 21)
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x101e8e49d, 17)
dyld_image_header_containing_address(0x101e66534)
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x101e8e4bf, 3)
dyld_image_header_containing_address(0x101e8e4bf)
dyld_image_header_containing_address(0x101e66534)
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x1740f8100, 55)
dladdr(0x101e58000, 0x16dead5b0)
2016-09-22 10:00:43.415261 iMomeetInHouse[16929:2902048] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x1700f9500, 35)
dladdr(0x18c072000, 0x16fd6e060)
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x1700fa280, 40)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x18d6a84b0)
dlopen_preflight(/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork, 0x00000115)
  dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork) ==> 0x1019fd369
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x1740f9380, 37)
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffe, CFGetTypeID)
  dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, CFGetTypeID) ==> 0x18cea25e8
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffe, CFStringGetCString)
  dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, CFStringGetCString) ==> 0x18cea7210
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffe, CFCopyDebugDescription)
  dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, CFCopyDebugDescription) ==> NULL
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffe, CFCopyDescription)
  dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, CFCopyDescription) ==> 0x18cee6aa0
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffe, CFRelease)
  dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, CFRelease) ==> 0x18cea23e8
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffe, CFStringGetCStringPtr)
  dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, CFStringGetCStringPtr) ==> 0x18cea67f0
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffe, CFStringGetLength)
  dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, CFStringGetLength) ==> 0x18cea79bc
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffe, CFNumberGetTypeID)
  dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, CFNumberGetTypeID) ==> 0x18cecac4c
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffe, CFStringGetTypeID)
  dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, CFStringGetTypeID) ==> 0x18ceaa148
dlsym(0xfffffffffffffffe, _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc)
  dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc) ==> 0x18d9aa358
dladdr(0x18ce9d000, 0x16e051720)
2016-09-22 10:00:43.462601 iMomeetInHouse[16929:2902035] [strings] ERROR: Err311 not found in table Localizable of bundle <private>
dladdr(0x18ce9d000, 0x16e051720)
2016-09-22 10:00:43.463023 iMomeetInHouse[16929:2902035] [strings] ERROR: Err-1022 not found in table Localizable of bundle <private>
_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x1740f9780, 31)

_dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x1700f9e00, 30)
iMomeetInHouse(16929,0x1b1e36c40) malloc: stack logs deleted from /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7CD18EE9-0509-43EB-BA84-88C7BC509743/tmp/stack-logs.16929.102024000.iMomeetInHouse.wQKXa7.index
```

Do you have any ideas on this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to clean project folder within Xcode, close it, delete DerivedData folder, delete the app from device/simulator and tried to build and run again?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu yes of course, but it can't help !

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting some video, audio, microphone access immediately after the app start? Then it might be a missing purpose string in your `Info.plist`.

> Starting in iOS 10, your Info.plist file must include a purpose string, for display in the permission alert, for each such item. If your app attempts to access a protected item without you having provided a corresponding purpose string, *your app exits.*

See [App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW6) for more detailed info.

Comment: The problem with those strings are fixed, but the app still crash and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You find in build phrases "libcoretls_cfhelpers.tbd" and choose optional for this library. It solve with me.