# Error Sockets SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sockets, ios10

```
KeyboardExtension[65191:2547754] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
KeyboardExtension[65191:2547754] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
    [x86_64] libnetcore-856.20.4
0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010f6a4682 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001100b7932 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3100
2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001100954f4 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000110094511 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000110093270 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001100ae44d nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001100ade7c nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001100c5ae5 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f44e12e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f4319d5 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 578
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f44277d _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 192
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f43b5a9 _dispatch_source_invoke + 1259
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f43331f _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 502
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f433cf3 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1118
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f435a0e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 506
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f4357b4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 113
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f7f44de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010f7f2341 start_wqthread + 13
```

I'm using `xcode 8.1` version with `ios 10`. I'm working with API's in keyboard. While executing the extension I am getting the above crash in console logs.

I have already gone through [Error: Protocol not available, dumping backtrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545603/error-protocol-not-available-dumping-backtrace) question & tried the accepted answer, but still I am getting this error in my logs.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an internal error in UIKit.  According to Apple Bug Report Radar `4468254630` this was fixed in iOS 11 Beta 1.