# Why I am getting Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, xcode9

When I redirect from main viewController to another viewController 
I'm getting this

**Error:**

> Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework,
>
> Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework,
>
> System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   path is
>   /Users/develop/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/083C0102-C85F-463A-96F4-CA1B9AC7919D/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/
>   systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

My code is...

**Appdelegate.m**

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Launched first time");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Already launched");
    [self getData];
}
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        LoginPageViewController *lpvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LPVC"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:lpvc animated:NO];
    });
} else {
    // My code...
}
```

Comment: When I commenting this line it's working properly..[self.navigationController pushViewController:lpvc animated:NO];

Comment: why geting the main thread in viewDidLoad? , I think viewDidLoad itself is on main thread

Comment: I want to redirect to login page when it's first launch...can u give any solution for me

Comment: Notes: this issue is specific to Xcode 9 and happens in Swift as well or without any navigationcontroller.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The message you have is from Xcode 9.
The equivalent message in Xcode 8 would be:

> [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/develop/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/083C0102-C85F-463A-96F4-CA1B9AC7919D/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

Note the `[MC]`:
It is a system message. This message can safely be ignored.

To hide this kind of messages, follow the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42140442/1033581:

1. Under Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... > Run, set the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE environment variable to ${DEBUG_ACTIVITY_MODE} so it looks like this:

[image: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE environment variable to ${DEBUG_ACTIVITY_MODE}]

2. Go to your project build settings, and click + to add a User-Defined Setting named DEBUG_ACTIVITY_MODE. Expand this setting and Click the + next to Debug to add a platform-specific value. Select the dropdown and change it to "Any iOS Simulator SDK". Then set its value to "default" so it looks like this:

[image: User-Defined setting DEBUG_ACTIVITY_MODE]

Comment: You could just redirect him to the answer you mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39573801/465235

Comment: @YassineElBadaoui, no, using `disable` is not what I recommend. I recommend `default` to avoid losing your own NSLog on Xcode 9.

Answer (score 0):

Update code in your app delegate.

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:"HasLaunchedOnce"]){
       LoginPageViewController *lpvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LPVC"];
       self.window.rootViewController = lpvc;
       NSLog(@"Launched first time");
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}else {
      MainViewController *mainVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
      self.window.rootViewController = mainVC;
     NSLog(@"Already launched");
     [self getData];
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 getting the same problem.. For solution 2 where need to write this code

Comment: I am getting in appdelegate self.storyboard not found error

Comment: self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                             bundle: nil];

Comment: yes, you have to make outlets for storyboard and window, Is it working now?

Comment: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch now I ma getting this error

Comment: Check your if else there might be a login issue, You need to set rootViewController in both.

Comment: Ok, thank u for spending your valuable time for me, but I am getting the same error...