# What is lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework?

Tags: xcode

When I run my app, in console i see:

```
2017-10-06 21:53:06.021357+0200 VocalDC[11885:697422] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2017-10-06 21:53:06.022797+0200 VocalDC[11885:697422] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2017-10-06 21:53:06.044053+0200 VocalDC[11885:697422] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/matteo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/30794E7C-3841-4E37-B559-75029A6D1645/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
```

why?

Comment: Perhaps duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46439892/

Answer (score 0):

This only started to appear with Xcode 9, ios 11.  It is a debug message in the format of the new "import os" logging system that we are all supposed to be adopting, right? It is from some system code debug statement.  You likely have a UTI import or export defined in your setup.  I don't get the first line or the last line but I get the "Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework" line.