# How to fix the Xcode logging issue with react-native

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, react-native

When I run react-native, and then try to get the console logs through `react-native log-ios`, I get a flooding of unhelpful logs that come from Xcode as is described [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545603/error-protocol-not-available-dumping-backtrace) and [here](http://php.wekeepcoding.com/article/12207721/xcode+console+flooded+with+excessive+logging+since+Swift+3+migration+%5Bduplicate%5D).

My problem is that when going through react-native, Xcode is not explicitly open and hence I cannot apply the fix described in the links.

This fix is to set the `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` variable to `Disable` from the product->scheme menu of Xcode.

Is there a way to set this environment variable when working from react-native?

Or any other way to this `SO_NOAPNFALLBK` error that floods the logs?

Comment: Ah that is because this command is not working for some reason, use `react-native-log-ios` npm pkg as a work around