# Disable extra information from the Xcode 8 console for iOS 10

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Ive just updated to the new Xcode 8, but when i run my application it give lots of console information "*only when i plug an iOS +10 device or iPhone 7 simulator*" but does not show the desired log because of the new information that the logs shows such as:

```
nw_endpoint_handler_cancel
nw_resolver_cancel_on_queue
tcp_connection_cancel
sa_dst_compare_internal
```

How to disable those things?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461256/1171066)

Just set an environment variable `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable` in your debug scheme. For reference see the image below

[image]

Comment: I saw this answer on twitter, but i couldn't find the "environment variable"

Comment: @Mutawe, have a look at this [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/p7BlV.png). From Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

Comment: This solution will hide all NSLog starting with Xcode 9. To keep NSLog, replace `disable` with `default`.