# System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, xcode8

When i run my application in ios 10 using xcode 8 i am getting below message in debug console but everything is working fine. My application is using camera and photo library, and i had added " **Privacy - Camera Usage Description** " and "**Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description**"in info.plist. Can any one tell me why this message in comming

> [MC] System group container for
>   systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

Comment: Same here.  I've added the keys, yet still these messages.

Comment: It happens to me when the keyboard is being shown.

Comment: What is your Privacy - Camera Usage Description?

Comment: Same here. I've added the keys, yet still these messages. 2

Comment: @AlexLacayo Not yet, still i am facing the same issue

Comment: @JAL "$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses camera"  and  "$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses photos"  this are the descriptions that i had given

Comment: @vais yea same. Created a blank project with 1 view controller and dropped in a textview. When I build the app, and then click inside the textview i get this.

Comment: Same here, so annoying!

Comment: I get it too, it seems to be a Xcode or iOS bug.

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51239   issue reported in developer forum

Answer (score 11):

If everything is working fine, then you should disregard these log messages. iOS has been printing a lot of irrelevant debug messages lately and I'm betting this is just another one of them.

You can also try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461256/1470317) from another question that seems to remove most irrelevant logs.

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 10.x we need to add the Privacy Permissions for Photo library, Camera and Contacts. As you said, once you add the Keys like

"Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description"

then you will be able to use those internal apps inside your app.

In my case app was crashing when I use Camera and Photo lib inside my app without these entries in Info.plist.

Comment: what are the additions to the info.plist file?

Comment: 1.Privacy - Camera Usage Description  :  Used to capture photo or scan barcode,

2.Privacy - Contacts Usage Description  :  Used to access device contacts, 

3. Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description : Used to access Photo library

Comment: I had the same log message without having photos or camera access in my project. I believe that @Bruno Philipe answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I have this on a text field and keyboard doesn't open

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct.  My iOS app does not use any external Photo, Camera, Contacts, or other library (that I know of), yet this message is being printed to the log file anyway, the first time the user clicks in a text editing field.  I'm running on iOS 12.1, and developing on XCode 10.1.