# Animating constraint to push UIView above Keyboard issue

Tags: swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, uiviewanimation, nsnotificationcenter

I have this `CommentViewController`. It's embedded in a Container View. In this `CommentViewController`, there's a `UITableView` to display comments and `UIView` that contains a `UITextField` and a `UIButton`. The `UIView` that's containing those 2 objects is fixed via autolayout in the bottom, right and left to the Safe Area and top to the `UITableView`.

Now, when the user taps the `UITextField`, the whole view (with the button and the textfield inside) should be lifted above the keyboard. I'm trying to animated the bottom constraint of the view, but it's not working.

**This is the code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.textFieldViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame!.height
    }
}
```

**This is storyboard:**

[image]

**This is the result after you tap the text field.**

[image]

PS: when I tap on `UITextField`, the console shows this message:

`2018-06-04 14:11:52.471848+0300 AppName[91846:8829073] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/d/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C89347A2-1598-4F31-BBAC-1F98F970A248/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-06-04 14:11:52.472588+0300 Shippers[91846:8829073] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.`

Comment: If you need just the functionality. Check this out, https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: For [MC] messages, it's unrelated and you can ignore those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588500/system-group-container-for-systemgroup-com-apple-configurationprofiles-path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` after changing the constraint's constant

```
self.textFieldViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame!.height
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

//

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
```

**Edit:**

Setting constant property for the bottom constraint depends on which element is the first in the constraint so if the constraint looks like this

Here textfield is the first

> textfield_Bottom = view_Bottom * multiplier + constant.  —> then
>   constant must be minus as Y axis decrease when go to up  which what we
>   want to make the view goes up when keyboard is shown

Here view is the first

> view_Bottom   = textfield_Bottom * multiplier + constant.  —> then
>   constant must be  plus

Comment: try UIKeyboardDidShow

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, please?

Comment: Sadly, no. Again, no result. Could the issue be the fact that this `CommentViewController` is actually in the container view? Also, when I tap on the `UITextField` the console shows this message: (see my updated answer)

Comment: can you print anything inside the function to see whether it runs or not

Comment: Yes, I also had suspicions that the function was not being called, but it is. I see the printed statement

Comment: check if you have to set -(minus)keyboardFrame!.height instead of keyboardFrame!.height