# xcode change output of console information

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I keep on getting a lot of useless information that is cluttering my console in xcode.

How can I set it so it only displays `print()` statements?

Example of the verbose and useless infomration that is cluttering my console.

```
2016-10-03 14:36:10.128415 Flashkase[925:10619] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x2
2016-10-03 14:36:10.128756 Flashkase[925:10619] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received READ_CLOSE event
2016-10-03 14:36:10.129379 Flashkase[925:9955] [] tcp_connection_event_notify 5 event: TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_READ_CLOSE, reason: read closed, should deliver: true
2016-10-03 14:36:10.130021 Flashkase[925:10619] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x6
2016-10-03 14:36:10.130369 Flashkase[925:9955] [] tcp_connection_cancel 5
2016-10-03 14:36:10.130852 Flashkase[925:10619] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received READ_CLOSE event
2016-10-03 14:36:10.131183 Flashkase[925:10619] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received WRITE_CLOSE event
2016-10-03 14:36:10.131542 Flashkase[925:10619] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [5.1 104.219.248.47:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol disconnected
2016-10-03 14:36:10.131917 Flashkase[925:10619] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [5 flashkase.com:443 ready resolver (satisfied)]
2016-10-03 14:36:10.132231 Flashkase[925:10619] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [5.1 104.219.248.47:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-03 14:36:10.132561 Flashkase[925:10619] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [5.1 104.219.248.47:443 cancelled socket-flow (null)] Output protocol disconnected
2016-10-03 14:36:10.132881 Flashkase[925:10619] [] nw_resolver_cancel_on_queue 0x60800011eb10
2016-10-03 14:36:10.133128 Flashkase[925:10619] [] -[NWConcrete_tcp_connection dealloc] 5
```

Comment: This should help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs

Comment: Omg thank you so much

Comment: It is ok :) I had the same problem.