# Error in iOS 10 : Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, xcode8, uiimageasset

```
2016-10-05 13:36:21.383340 MyApp[1867:72704] 0x60000015e350 Copy matching assets reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x60000015e350> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "Result" => <int64: 0x600000226fe0>: 29
}
2016-10-05 13:36:21.385076 MyApp[1867:72704] 0x608000556420 Daemon configuration query reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x608000556420> { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "Dictionary" => <dictionary: 0x6080005566e0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
        "ServerURL" => <dictionary: 0x608000556790> { count = 3, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
            "com.apple.CFURL.magic" => <uuid: 0x60800024f720> C1234DCC-2276-5214-B6C1-FD9F5191212
            "com.apple.CFURL.string" => <string: 0x608000241ce0> { length = 30, contents = "https://mesu.apple.com/assets/" }
            "com.apple.CFURL.base" => <null: 0x112e42f20>: null-object
        }
    }
    "Result" => <int64: 0x6080004241e0>: 0
}
2016-10-05 13:36:21.385693 MyApp[1867:72704] [MobileAssetError:29] Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.TextInput.SpellChecker
```

I'm using **xcode 8** version with **ios 10**. If, I use project in **ios 9.3** its works fine but when same project I used in **ios 10** error message appears **Unable to copy asset information..**.

Comment: I get this too, but when the keyboard opens.

Comment: Add me to the list of complainers

Comment: me too. Seems to open a browser window, I see "Done" and inapp browser like navigation when I click into the field

Comment: Do you get this on device or simulator?

Comment: @pteofil Both on device and in simulator.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have end up with below solution. Follow the steps.

- Set the the Environment Variable in `Edit Scheme`.
  [image]
- Restart the xcode.
- Clean & build xcode.

& than work perfectly on my side.

Comment: Have a look at this Q/A (http://stackoverflow.com/q/37800790/2778898). Using this method will disable all NSLogs...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in iOS10 and xcode 8. Same error after applying this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this code, you made a great day

Comment: Although this seemingly disables the error. All it does is mute the diagnostics. It does nothing to alleviate the problem.

In my case the error is being throw during the focus of an <input> within a UIWebView. Making the change above did in fact stop the error from happening. But the memory leak caused by the error still occurs.

Comment: This isn't exactly a "solution", all it's doing is hiding the error.

Answer (score 51):

Setting OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable doesn't resolve the issue but only turn off the logs

To fix the issue:

1- In storyboard select the TextView

2- From Xcode attributes inspector set:

Correction = No

Spell Checking = No

3- Fixed

The problem appears to happen because of failure to download assets for spell checking from:
http://mesu.apple.com/assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_TextInput_SpellChecker/com_apple_MobileAsset_TextInput_SpellChecker.xml

Hope this helps

Comment: This way I don't get the error - but also lose the autocorrection ability (obviously) on those inputs. So perhaps there is a better solution? Why does the failure occurs in downloading the asset?

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3 Update**

@guest answer fixes the problem. But incase if you are creating the `UITextView`programmatically.

```
textView.spellCheckingType = .no
textView.autocorrectionType = .no
```