# Errors IOS 10 - Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.TextInput.SpellChecker

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a set of UITextfield for users to be able to Sign Up. 
My app builds successfully but whenever I try to enter @ in the email text field it display the messages below and makes it impossible to register a user, the register button can not be clicked on. 
Does anyone know what is going on? and how can I fix this issue?

```
2017-04-14 15:41:26.949699-0400 Oja[72824:36708711] 0x6080003484b0 Copy matching assets reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x6080003484b0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"Result" => <int64: 0x608000222e40>: 29
}
2017-04-14 15:41:26.951188-0400 Oja[72824:36708711] 0x600000150e30 Daemon configuration query reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x600000150e30> { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"Dictionary" => <dictionary: 0x600000345800> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "ServerURL" => <dictionary: 0x600000344db0> { count = 3, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
        "com.apple.CFURL.magic" => <uuid: 0x600000043000> C3853DCC-9776-4114-B6C1-FD9F51944A6D
        "com.apple.CFURL.string" => <string: 0x6000000553c0> { length = 30, contents = "https://mesu.apple.com/assets/" }
        "com.apple.CFURL.base" => <null: 0x114b17f40>: null-object
    }
}
"Result" => <int64: 0x600000037360>: 0
}
2017-04-14 15:41:26.951649-0400 Oja[72824:36708711] [MobileAssetError:29] Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.TextInput.SpellChecker
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in iOS 10 : Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868842/error-in-ios-10-unable-to-copy-asset-information-from-https-mesu-apple-com-a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out programmatically. I added

```
tf.autocorrectionType = .no
```

to stop the spell check.

```
 let emailTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "Email Address"
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tf.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTextInputchange), for: .editingChanged)
    tf.autocorrectionType = .no
    return tf
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

just set auto correction and spell checking on textfield to No
and you're good to go
Straightforward, no bs, no muting the NSlog info, quick fix.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @Ola you can go to storyboard, and select the that textfield. Click the attribute inspector, which is on the right panel,you will see Correction is set to default and spell checking is also set to default, and you need to change them to No

Comment: thank you it worked, since I am not using the storyboard I did it a little differently using the your concept.