# Swift: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

This is my second project that I'm doing in Swift 3. I ran into this error code:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

and my project won't load correctly either. Please help!

Img: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac9yP.png]

UPDATE: WORKS NOW!

Comment: copy console error output please

Comment: scroll console up and search error

Comment: Just did nothing shows up

Comment: Still doing the same, but i need the Firebase for login.

Comment: Scroll console up and add the full callstack in the output window to your question. Someone might be able to help then

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have checked `initial view controller` from storyboard. Generally, this is the main reason for such type of crash.
[image: Inital View Controller]

[image]

Comment: Yeah it is checked. Still doing the same things.

Comment: can you please send me your crash log ?

Comment: Yes.. So please try to remove the outlet of passowrdField and connect it again

Comment: I'm new in coding swift. So you are saying that i have to remove this "@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!"?

Comment: Yes and please reconnect it again

Comment: I have updated my answer.. please see the second screenshot. Your storyboard passwordField would be showing yellow.

Comment: Have you seen exclamation mark on your LoginVC for passwordField ?

Comment: Yeah i see the yellow thing as well on mine.

Comment: So please remove it and try to make new outlet for passwordField. After that, It will work like charm

Comment: Oh i got you now. You wanted me to remove that and run it. I see that the project works now.

Comment: Okay did that now i see the project. When i try to sign up then it crash...

Comment: so please send me crash log once again

Comment: see the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868842/error-in-ios-10-unable-to-copy-asset-information-from-https-mesu-apple-com-a

Comment: Oh i think i got it. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Great...  @B. Alan  , You did it