# Text to Speech not working on background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using piece of code to speak my message with the help of `AVSpeechSynthesizer`. but i want same functionality to run on background mode. can we do it? Please tell me , how do i do it.

Thanks

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Driver Reached On Your Location"];
[utterance setRate:0.5f];
[synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVSpeechSynthesizer in background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183591/avspeechsynthesizer-in-background-mode)

Answer (score 0):

add this code in AppDelegate.m (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

please add **App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay** under "**Required background modes**" property on your plist file

[image]

Comment: Sorry i did not understand your answer, please be specific

Comment: i have done already but it is not working. i have found some text on log, please check
[TTS] Error running custom voice query Error Domain=ASError Code=15 "Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.VoiceServices.GryphonVoice" UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.VoiceServices.GryphonVoice}

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868842/error-in-ios-10-unable-to-copy-asset-information-from-https-mesu-apple-com-a