# UITextView errors in console on iOS 10 only – device works fine

Tags: iphone, ios10

UITextView throws errors in my console on iOS 10 only, but it's working fine on iPhone and it appears only when I update to iOS 10. In iOS 9.3 it is fine.

```
Copy matching assets reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x174147bc0> { count = 2, transer = 0x0, contents =
    "Assets" => <data: 0x17466e6c0>: { length = 2114 bytes, contents = 0x62706c6973743030d4010203040506e9ea58247665727369... }
    "Result" => <int64: 0x174430cc0>: 0
}
Copy assets attributes reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x170144ba0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "Result" => <int64: 0x170435e40>: 1
}
[MobileAssetError:1] Unable to copy asset attributes
2016-10-05 14:24:20.431267 EndPointScanning[5761:1474337] 0x170144830 Copy assets attributes reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x170144830> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "Result" => <int64: 0x170436860>: 1
}
[MobileAssetError:1] Unable to copy asset attributes
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs

Answer (score 9):

Works on **Swift3** iOS 10.*

On Xcode menu go to Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme...

Then select Arguments and add on the **Environment Variables** option -

> OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable

[image]

Comment: That is a correct answer. `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable` hmmm, maybe in future iOS marge with macOS or apps from iOS will work on macOS.