# MC System group container AND MC Reading from public effective user settings errors on keyboard appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Just upgraded to XCode 8 and my device to iOS 10, then I get this message the first time I enter any textField.

```
[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

[MC] Reading from public effective user settings errors.
```

My app is still functional, no problems, but I want to get rid of this warning before I submit it.

My app us written in Objective-C, if this makes a difference.

I know it's coming from the keyboard, because I've commented out all actions taken when entering the textField (and really it is any textField), and the error still occurs.

Is there a fix? And if not, would it be okay to submit it with this warning?

Comment: Try [Hide strange unwanted Xcode 8 logs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37800790)

Comment: yeah, i know about that ability, if you're referring to OS_ACTIVITY_MODE and it does prevent the warning from showing, but I'm worried that my app will be rejected with this warning.

Comment: Those aren't warnings, they are simple debug messages shown by iOS 10.

Comment: @maddy: what's the use of this messages?I am also getting above message.

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40458288), this is probably only log debug message that doesn't affect release version of the app

Comment: I see the same error when notifications are not being passed by a navigation controller into a pushed view: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65216. Will wait for a solution to post a possible answer.

Answer (score 8):

1- From Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

2- On your Environment Variables set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE in the value set disable

Comment: any explanation?

Comment: With this solution, you'll remove some important stuff out of the log when using real device. @VitoValov disabling OS_ACTIVITY_MODE in your XCode scheme will block debug logs from printing in the console.

Comment: Ignoring warnings isn't a solution