# Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" when using picked image with UIImagePickerController

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios11

I am trying to use an image picked using the standard UIImagePickerController in iOS 11. No matter how hard I try it just keeps showing this error:

`errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled`

I can actually pass the UIImage to the setter method, I can see the image in the inspector, but when I set it as a background image of a UIButton, it's just a plain black colour and when the UIImagePickerController dismisses, I get the error above.

I did request use the PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization and YES I have Read and Write access to Photos.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found a post from Antoine Richeux which solves the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608761/picker-error-message-on-exit-encountered-while-discovering-extensions-error-do

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you did not use UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage or UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage but rather another non-image editing option for UIImagePickerController.

I experienced the same/similar error. 
[image]

The app ran yet the image showed as black. The line I used to assign the image originally looked like this:

```
let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? UIImage
```

and was resolved by changing the line to this:

```
let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error what worked from me is adding the uinavigationcontrollerdelegate to my file and then declaring the uiimagepickercontroller as self in the view did load.
example

```
class notesview: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
viewdidload(){
imagepicker.delegate = self

}
 }
```

Comment: Nope, did not work, I have it set as a lazy var and the delegate is there