# TIC TCP Conn Error on iOS 10 logs

Tags: ios, ios10

Is anyone getting the following CFNetwork notices in their iOS 10 logs?

```
(CFNetwork)[1142] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Event [28:0x1741845e0]: 1 Err(0)
(CFNetwork)[1142] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Connected [28:0x1741845e0]: Err(0)
(CFNetwork)[1142] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Cancel [28:0x1741845e0]
```

I don't get any of these in my iOS 9 logs. It's not clear if this is causing anything to break. Any ideas what this is, what it's breaking or how to fix it?

Comment: This should do the trick:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs/39461256#39461256

Comment: That didn't change anything, still getting the same lines in my iOS 10 logs.

Comment: it causing me some issue in XMPP push receiving but not sure what;s that.

Comment: Any resolution to this issue?

Comment: I still haven't found a resolution @JeroenLeenarts

Answer (score 0):

remove NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent key from info.plist

Comment: What if you need NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent but still don't want to see these in the console?