# Xcode 8.1 beta 3 - AQDefaultDevice messages

Tags: audio, xcode8, beta

As of beta2, I'm getting this message every two seconds after I create an audio output unit:

```
2016-10-14 11:31:21.572479 MyProduct[94063:8294923] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0
```

Anyone know what it's generated by?
I'd thought that perhaps I wasn't servicing an audio out callback, but as far as I can tell, I'm servicing it properly.

Answer (score 10):

A cleaner solution (than the one given by user6026720) that fixes Simulator logs without affecting Device logs is available at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39651073/1033581:

1. Under Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... > Run, set the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE environment variable to ${DEBUG_ACTIVITY_MODE} so it looks like this:

[image: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE environment variable to ${DEBUG_ACTIVITY_MODE}]

2. Go to your project build settings, and click + to add a User-Defined Setting named DEBUG_ACTIVITY_MODE. Expand this setting and Click the + next to Debug to add a platform-specific value. Select the dropdown and change it to "Any iOS Simulator SDK". Then set its value to "disable" so it looks like this:

[image: User-Defined setting DEBUG_ACTIVITY_MODE]