# XCode 8.0 Console gives incomplete API response while running on Devices

Tags: iphone, xcode8, ios10

I got incomplete API response in console of XCode 8.0 while I running my project on devices (here with I attached the incomplete response that I got). Although I got correct response while running simulators.

How can I fix it?

```
     {
  "meta": {
    "total-pages": 13
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "articles",
      "id": "3",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!",
        "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
        "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
```

Comment: I think its not XCode 8 problem, I think many unwanted log print in console so you can't able to see your full response, Can you just try to stop unwanted log :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/39461256/3752143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in the global header:

`#define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", [[NSString` `stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);`