# recordFailureWithDescription("Custom Description", inFile: #file, atLine: #line, expected: true) is not working xcode 8 UI xctest

Tags: xcode8, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xctestcase

When using XCTest method recordFailureWithDescription like this:

```
func testRecordFailureMessageNotWorking() {
    XCUIApplication().button["Login"].tap()
    self.recordFailureWithDescription("Custom Description", inFile: #file, atLine: #line, expected: true)
}
```

The console output no longer provides the custom description or the file name or the line number as it did in xcode 7.

Anyone have any thoughts on this? or a way to get the custom description?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your OS to macOS Sierra - this will improve the console functionality.

Comment: Although I have not upgraded to Sierra, I am not sure this will solve my problem.  I would like the custom description added to the failure description so it is accessible from external programs like xcpretty etc.

Answer (score -1):

Xcode 8 changed the output for logs, for me it included a lot of 'garbage' code. Are you getting any of that or is it just the omission of the file name/ line number that is affecting you? If its the former, you can edit the projects scheme:

1- From Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

2- On your Environment Variables set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable

The above is detailed more here:
[Hide strange unwanted Xcode 8 logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs)

(Sorry if I am totally off, first time poster)