# Application crashed on non-debug mode

Tags: ios, sockets, crash, swift3

I am using xcode 8, ios10 and 10.11.6 OS version. I install the application on iPhone. Now when I run the application, the application crashed. Using `leak instruments`, I found these errors:-

> 2016-11-23 14:24:03.236062 pkcClub[1657:490070] []
>   nw_socket_write_close shutdown(13, SHUT_WR): [57] Socket is not
>   connected 2016-11-23 14:24:03.238053 pkcClub[1657:490070] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [3.1 52.172.8.106:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 0 frame count, 0 byte count
>   2016-11-23 14:24:03.248774 pkcClub[1657:490068] []
>   __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled

What is this `nw_socket_write_close shutdown`?

Comment: Please     Select Product => Scheme => Edit Scheme or use shortcut : CMD + <
    Select the Run option from left side.
    On Environment Variables section, add the variable OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = false.  After that run the application and see the log.

Answer (score 0):

The log you show us is not a reason to the crash.
You can see detail about the log you push.

[Hide strange unwanted Xcode 8 logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs)?

After, you could get useful information from the console.