# Xcode not showing crash/error output

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode8

I have an issue. Xcode not showing issue when applicaiton crashed. Its just showing error on below.

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide strange unwanted Xcode 8 logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I just solved the problem. To solve my problem, I changed the following value:

`OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable`

to

`OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = enable`

and it worked.

Comment: Solved it for me as well! Thanks for the hint... It makes the debugger unreadable as it logs so much **** but at least now it shows me my crash-reasons again :) thx!!!