# Swift mysterious error

Tags: ios, swift, siesta

I'm receiving mysterious error messages while debugging my swift app on my iPhone.

This message gets displayed while a performSegue after a Siesta-API-Call:

```
2016-12-06 11:08:36.032131 dl[20878:6372455] [Common] _BSMachError: port 9913; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2016-12-06 11:08:36.032664 dl[20878:6372455] [Common] _BSMachError: port 9913; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to deallocate send right"
```

And this messages pops up after closing the app over the home button:

```
2016-12-06 11:08:52.609482 dl[20878:6372455] Cannot snapshot view (<UIKeyboardImpl: 0x13fe16770; frame = (0 0; 414 226); layer = <CALayer: 0x17403eda0>>) with afterScreenUpdates:NO, because the view is not in a window. Use afterScreenUpdates:YES.
```

The started appearing somehow.
Any ideas how to fix these?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs

Comment: Tried that already but without success.. I'm debugging it on my iPhone and the second warning still shows up..

Comment: But the first one is an error, or am I wrong?

Comment: For me it looks like `OS_ACTIVITY`.

Comment: Found out that the error was caused by a "Please Wait" AlertController which was not dismissed correctly before doing a segue

Answer (score 4):

See last comment..

Error was caused by an "Please Wait" AlertController which was not dismissed correctly before doing a segue..

Comment: I was not doing a seque but apparently a call to popViewController causes the same error. I fixed it by dispatching all of the code to the main thread asynchronously so it would get run after the alert controller is done/gone/dismissed/destroyed.