# I'm getting a compiler message using Realm with Swift 3.0.2 but no error

Tags: swift, swift3, realm

This is the first time I use Realm, I'm using the version for Swift 3.0.2 and everything seem to be working fine except that I'm getting the following compiler message.

Any idea why am I getting this message?

Is this something to worry about in a real project?

```
2016-12-25 12:31:59.618648 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.618908 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.619978 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.621073 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.622681 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.625555 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.628054 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.631461 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.633917 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.635952 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.638214 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.640755 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.643027 RealmTestProject[41887:3081907] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.648197 RealmTestProject[41887:3081906] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-25 12:31:59.651309 RealmTestProject[41887:3081906] [] ____nwlog_simulate_crash_inner_block_invoke dlopen CrashReporterSupport failed
2016-12-25 12:31:59.651572 RealmTestProject[41887:3081906] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash failed "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2016-12-25 12:31:59.652240 RealmTestProject[41887:3081906] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.30.16
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010daf8666 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ec88006 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3164
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ec65555 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ec64572 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ec63298 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ec7eae1 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ec7e510 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ec961f9 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d875978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d89f0cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d87ce17 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d87db4b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d880385 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d880059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010dc484de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010dc46341 start_wqthread + 13
```

Here is my testing Code:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addHuman()
        queryPeople()
    }

    func addHuman(){
        let mike = Human()
        mike.name = "Mike"
        mike.age = 15
        mike.race = "US"

        let realm = try! Realm()

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(mike)
            debugPrint("Added \(mike.name) to Realm")
        }
    }

    func queryPeople(){
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let allPeople = realm.objects(Human.self)

        for person in allPeople{
            print("Person: \(person.name) is \(person.age) years old and is from \(person.race)")
        }
    }
}
```

Human Class:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Human : Object{

    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    dynamic var race = ""
}
```

Comment: Do you get it on writing to Realm or on reading? Or both ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979453/xcode-console-flooded-with-excessive-logging-since-swift-3-migration

Comment: @MartinR -  I added the variable as described in the following thread and it solve my problem, the message went away. Thanks a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs