# How do I hide console output for specific projects in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I’m working on a project where I’m using an SDK provided by someone else, installed as a Cocoapod dependency.  But there are a lot of logging statements that get printed out to the debugger from one of the installed pods.

Is there a way to disable console output for a specific target or project?
For example, anything in my `Pods` project which is part of my workspace.

I found information on how to disable all logging using something like this:

[Hide Strange Unwanted Xcode 8 Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs)

But this disables logging for the entire workspace, and I still want to have my information from the code that I am working on.

Thanks in advance for your help!