# How to fix XCode png logs?

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog

```
0 created png2: 0x1402a4000
1 created png2: 0x1402a4000
0 created png2: 0x1408f3800
1 created png2: 0x1408f3800
0 created png2: 0x1408f3800
1 created png2: 0x1408f3800
0 created png2: 0x1408f3800
1 created png2: 0x140138c00
0 created png2: 0x1402a4000
1 created png2: 0x1402a4000
0 created png2: 0x1402a4000
1 created png2: 0x140992600
0 created png2: 0x1402a4000
```

XCode generating unknown log in console, which is about png
How can I fix this???

***Note : Its only appear when I run on device.***

Comment: Have you tried `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` as `disable` from `environment variable`??

Comment: Yes, Its not working in this case

Comment: Debug activity mode disable kar thai jase.  Jo aa link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs

Comment: @sschunara : I did this ...but that only disable methods debug log...this is something new...thanks shashibhai ..(y)