# Unclear logs flood at the console

Tags: macos, keychain

I can see a lot of repeated logs at the console with the form:

```
Subsystem: com.apple.securityd Category: dbsession  
DataGetNext(6080002782bb)  
and
Subsystem: com.apple.securityd Category: dbsession  
FreeUniqueRecord: 6080002782bb
```

I have a suspect that might cause this - the keyChain, but I'm not really sure, and I don't know if it's even a problem or just internal OS stuff.

Anyone has a clue what are those logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's OS developers may be trying to give us more useful information to work with, but for 99% of developers, most of these messages are simply gibberish.  It also may be that they forgot to disable (or make user-configurable) `securityd` logging.  Developers have been complaining about this [ever since Xcode 8 was introduced](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/151814#151814).

[To squelch them, you can add `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE=disable` in your app's debug scheme or into your environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs/39461256#39461256).

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but how can I be sure those logs don't suggest I did something wrong?