# How to remove verbose network messages from xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Xcode is showing me a ton of network messages in the debug console.  So all my debug messages get lost.  Here's an example of what I'm seeing:

```
2017-03-16 12:13:09.240955 App[92733:67782831] bundleid: com.domain.App, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:09.243566 App[92733:67782831] subsystem: com.apple.siri, category: Intents, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 1, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:09.276874 App[92733:67783026] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:09.277568 App[92733:67783026] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:09.296883 App[92733:67783016] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:09.318627 App[92733:67782831] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:09.375 [info][tid:main][RCTBatchedBridge.m:74] Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x60000019d8e0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6000000a4440>, executor: RCTJSCExecutor)
2017-03-16 12:13:09.382749 App[92733:67783015] subsystem: com.apple.libsqlite3, category: logging, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:09.493836 App[92733:67783015] subsystem: com.apple.network, category: , enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:09.496102 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [2 192.168.1.14:8081 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:09.497432 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2 192.168.1.14:8081 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2017-03-16 12:13:09.504666 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2 192.168.1.14:8081 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:09.528822 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2 192.168.1.14:8081 waiting path (satisfied)] skipping state update
2017-03-16 12:13:09.548227 App[92733:67783017] subsystem: com.apple.SystemConfiguration, category: SCPreferences, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:09.553066 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2 192.168.1.14:8081 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:09.602486 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:09.603700 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2017-03-16 12:13:09.606444 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:09.607511 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 waiting path (satisfied)] skipping state update
2017-03-16 12:13:09.614532 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:start_dns
2017-03-16 12:13:09.619692 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [2 192.168.1.14:8081 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected
2017-03-16 12:13:09.625094 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [2 192.168.1.14:8081 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Connected path is satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:09.625481 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2 192.168.1.14:8081 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:09.626143 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2 192.168.1.14:8081 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:changed_viability
2017-03-16 12:13:09.765123 App[92733:67782831] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:09.768658 App[92733:67782831] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Touch, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:09.861584 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 54.243.93.187:443
2017-03-16 12:13:09.865186 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 54.235.86.237:443
2017-03-16 12:13:09.873449 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 54.243.255.60:443
2017-03-16 12:13:09.880069 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 54.235.101.104:443
2017-03-16 12:13:09.888963 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 54.243.160.177:443
2017-03-16 12:13:09.895027 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 54.243.58.1:443
2017-03-16 12:13:09.898811 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 54.225.233.150:443
2017-03-16 12:13:09.909875 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 54.225.244.34:443
2017-03-16 12:13:09.912642 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:receive_dns
2017-03-16 12:13:09.913439 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting child endpoint 54.243.93.187:443
2017-03-16 12:13:09.913979 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting next child endpoint in 100ms
2017-03-16 12:13:09.914646 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:09.935967 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2017-03-16 12:13:09.956894 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:09.964428 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:09.986362 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected
2017-03-16 12:13:09.988304 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Connected path is satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:09.988999 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:09.991250 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 ready resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:09.992507 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:changed_viability
2017-03-16 12:13:09.993229 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 ready resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:changed_viability
2017-03-16 12:13:09.996738 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_start_tls_while_connected [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2017-03-16 12:13:10.000468 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_secondary_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:10.005757 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_secondary_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:10.009391 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:10.010355 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:10.011747 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Transport protocol connected
2017-03-16 12:13:10.012110 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_transport
2017-03-16 12:13:10.013021 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_transport
2017-03-16 12:13:10.042587 App[92733:67782831] subsystem: com.apple.securityd, category: OSStatus, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:10.243699 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected
2017-03-16 12:13:10.246419 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Connected path is satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:10.246727 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:10.247650 App[92733:67783035] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 ready resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:10.348556 App[92733:67782831] subsystem: com.apple.SystemConfiguration, category: SCNetworkReachability, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:10.390217 App[92733:67783036] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1 settings.crashlytics.com:443 ready resolver (satisfied)]
2017-03-16 12:13:10.390446 App[92733:67783036] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2017-03-16 12:13:10.390738 App[92733:67783036] [] __nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke sendmsg(fd 13, 31 bytes): socket has been closed
2017-03-16 12:13:10.391064 App[92733:67783036] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [1.1 54.243.93.187:443 cancelled socket-flow (null)] Output protocol disconnected
2017-03-16 12:13:10.391299 App[92733:67783036] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.2 54.235.86.237:443 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:10.402250 App[92733:67782831] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureEnvironment, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-16 12:13:10.612353 App[92733:67783036] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.3 54.243.255.60:443 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:10.748023 App[92733:67783036] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.4 54.235.101.104:443 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:10.749675 App[92733:67783036] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.5 54.243.160.177:443 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:10.756269 App[92733:67783036] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.6 54.243.58.1:443 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:10.757065 App[92733:67783036] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.7 54.225.233.150:443 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:10.757367 App[92733:67783036] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.8 54.225.244.34:443 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:11.040927 App[92733:67783062] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [3 192.168.1.14:8081 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:11.160625 App[92733:67783062] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3 192.168.1.14:8081 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2017-03-16 12:13:11.164162 App[92733:67783062] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3 192.168.1.14:8081 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:11.164758 App[92733:67783062] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3 192.168.1.14:8081 waiting path (satisfied)] skipping state update
2017-03-16 12:13:11.165582 App[92733:67783062] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3 192.168.1.14:8081 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:11.166746 App[92733:67783062] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [3 192.168.1.14:8081 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected
2017-03-16 12:13:11.168700 App[92733:67783062] [] nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [3 192.168.1.14:8081 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Connected path is satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:11.169121 App[92733:67783062] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3 192.168.1.14:8081 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:11.169548 App[92733:67783062] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3 192.168.1.14:8081 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:changed_viability
2017-03-16 12:13:11.394712 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [4 localhost:8097 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:11.395130 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4 localhost:8097 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2017-03-16 12:13:11.396040 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4 localhost:8097 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:11.396268 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4 localhost:8097 waiting path (satisfied)] skipping state update
2017-03-16 12:13:11.396697 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:start_dns
2017-03-16 12:13:11.398284 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for ::1.8097
2017-03-16 12:13:11.398556 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for fe80::1%lo0.8097@lo0
2017-03-16 12:13:11.398886 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 127.0.0.1:8097
2017-03-16 12:13:11.399092 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:receive_dns
2017-03-16 12:13:11.399582 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting child endpoint ::1.8097
2017-03-16 12:13:11.400402 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting next child endpoint in 100ms
2017-03-16 12:13:11.400823 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [4.1 ::1.8097 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:11.401339 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.1 ::1.8097 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2017-03-16 12:13:11.402349 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.1 ::1.8097 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:11.403127 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.1 ::1.8097 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:11.405494 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [4.1 ::1.8097 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol disconnected
2017-03-16 12:13:11.406991 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.1 ::1.8097 failed socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:failed_connect, error Error Domain=kNWErrorDomainPOSIX Code=61 "Connection refused" UserInfo={NSDescription=Connection refused}
2017-03-16 12:13:11.407717 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] all started children failed, start next child.
2017-03-16 12:13:11.408393 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting child endpoint fe80::1%lo0.8097@lo0
2017-03-16 12:13:11.409020 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting next child endpoint in 100ms
2017-03-16 12:13:11.409675 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [4.2 fe80::1%lo0.8097@lo0 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:11.410257 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.2 fe80::1%lo0.8097@lo0 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2017-03-16 12:13:11.411219 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.2 fe80::1%lo0.8097@lo0 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:11.412854 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.2 fe80::1%lo0.8097@lo0 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:11.414166 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [4.2 fe80::1%lo0.8097@lo0 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol disconnected
2017-03-16 12:13:11.414912 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.2 fe80::1%lo0.8097@lo0 failed socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:failed_connect, error Error Domain=kNWErrorDomainPOSIX Code=61 "Connection refused" UserInfo={NSDescription=Connection refused}
2017-03-16 12:13:11.415703 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] all started children failed, start next child.
2017-03-16 12:13:11.416352 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting child endpoint 127.0.0.1:8097
2017-03-16 12:13:11.416850 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting next child endpoint in 100ms
2017-03-16 12:13:11.417097 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [4.3 127.0.0.1:8097 initial path (null)]
2017-03-16 12:13:11.417360 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.3 127.0.0.1:8097 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2017-03-16 12:13:11.417881 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.3 127.0.0.1:8097 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2017-03-16 12:13:11.418178 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.3 127.0.0.1:8097 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2017-03-16 12:13:11.418781 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [4.3 127.0.0.1:8097 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol disconnected
2017-03-16 12:13:11.419092 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4.3 127.0.0.1:8097 failed socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:failed_connect, error Error Domain=kNWErrorDomainPOSIX Code=61 "Connection refused" UserInfo={NSDescription=Connection refused}
2017-03-16 12:13:11.419441 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [4 localhost:8097 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] all children failed
2017-03-16 12:13:11.419908 App[92733:67783017] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [4 localhost:8097 failed resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:children_failed
2017-03-16 12:13:11.420354 App[92733:67783017] [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 4 Connection has no connected handler
2017-03-16 12:13:11.421068 App[92733:67783063] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [4 localhost:8097 failed resolver (satisfied)]
2017-03-16 12:13:11.421359 App[92733:67783063] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [4.1 ::1.8097 failed socket-flow (satisfied)]
2017-03-16 12:13:11.421616 App[92733:67783063] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [4.2 fe80::1%lo0.8097@lo0 failed socket-flow (satisfied)]
2017-03-16 12:13:11.421920 App[92733:67783063] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [4.3 127.0.0.1:8097 failed socket-flow (satisfied)]
```

**Update**:  It turns out a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs) was already asked but I had a very hard time finding it because my logs were different than the ones in the other question.  Although the answers are the same, I think my question is helpful for other people (like me) who have a hard time finding a solution when searching for questions with log messages from a react native app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

To turn off Verbose for OS Activity Mode

1. From the xcode menu, Project -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme.
2. Then select `Run` on the left and then select `Arguments` tab on the right.
3. In `Environment Variables` add the name `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and value as `disable`.

Or see picture below.

[image]

Note: credit for image goes to [Ramkrishna Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40463835/1078829)

Comment: OMG Thank you! I've been trying to get rid of this garbage for many months now. Finally this is what I needed!

Comment: hmm, that removed logs coming from my own library...