# Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates

Tags: logging, ios11, xcode9-beta

When debugging app in Xcode 9 beta while it's running on iPhone with iOS 11 beta installed, I started to notice following messages when performing networking calls:

```
[] network_config_register_boringssl_log_debug_updates Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates
[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_npn_data: line 1212 Peer's advertised NPN data is NULL or empty
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: A question about this was posted here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79025

What is BoringSSL for?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### UPDATE

There's actually a very convenient way to silence certain logs for a specific simulator:

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --subsystem com.apple.network --category boringssl --mode level:off
```

It is also recommended to silence other common non-important logs as well:

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --subsystem com.apple.CoreBluetooth --mode level:off
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony --mode level:off
```

---

#### Original answer (background)

These annoying messages come from `libboringssl.dylib :: boringssl_metrics_log_event`:

```
int boringssl_metrics_log_event(...) {
  ...
  if (g_boringssl_log != nil && os_log_type_enabled(g_boringssl_log, OS_LOG_TYPE_ERROR) {
    os_log_error(g_boringssl_log, "%s(%d) Failed to log metrics", "boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke", 151);
  }
  ...
}
```

An easy way to silence these messages is to nullify `g_boringssl_log`.

`g_boringssl_log` is a global variable:

```
os_log_t g_boringssl_log = nil;
```

It gets initialized in `boringssl_log_open`:

```
void boringssl_log_open() {
   static dispatch_token onceToken = nil;
   dispatch_once(onceToken, ^{
     g_boringssl_log = os_log_create("com.apple.network", "boringssl");
   });
}
```

IMO the easiest solution to nullify `g_boring_ssl` is to skip the execution of `dispatch_once`.

That could be achieved with setting a breakpoint to `__boringssl_log_open_block_invoke` with action `thread return`. This breakpoint will be called once thanks to `dispatch_once`, but the function's body will not be executed because of immediate `thread return`. So `g_boringssl_log` will never be initialized, and there will be no logs in the Console.

PS I might also recommend setting a similar breakpoint for `____nwlog_connection_log_block_invoke` from `libnetwork.dylib`.

[image: An example of breakpoint]

Comment: It's not really clear what you did there, can you try another explanation?

Comment: @Arturo in Xcode go to menu Debug > Breakpoints > Create Symbolic Breakpoint and fill the form following storoj screenshot

Answer (score 7):

Open the Xcode Scheme editor and add a new environment variable `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and set to `disable`.

NOTE: Beware, this will disable ALL NSLog outputs, not just the BoringSSL messages.

[image]

Comment: What does this do exactly?

Comment: This approach seems to stop all NSLog logging, which is a problem. For a more nuanced approach that builds on this answer, above, but does not eliminate all NSLog logging, see the answer by cduhn at [Hide strange unwanted Xcode 8 logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs).

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? The question was "What is causing this?", not "How do I hide it?"

Comment: This answer suppresses the logs, but there is no explanation about the actual error and there is no mention about exact fix for it.

Comment: This solution should not be accepted - it causes important diagnostic messages to disappear.

Comment: In addition to hiding NSLog outputs as other have mentioned, it also hides os_log outputs. Beware.

Comment: This will just silence all system logs, even the ones that you need to see.

Comment: Sorry guys, I asked this question a while ago and now revisited it after quite some time and noticed new proper answer. Marked it as an accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Xcode and select your project.
- Go to the "Project Navigator" and select the root project node.
- Select the "General" tab at the top of the project editor.
- Scroll down to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section.
- Look for the library you want to check for updates (e.g. BoringSSL) and
  find the version number listed next to it.
- Search for the latest version of that library online, either on the
  library's official website or on a package manager such as CocoaPods or
  Carthage.
- Compare the version number you found in Xcode with the latest version
  available online.
- If there is a newer version available, follow the steps provided by the
  library or package manager to update to the latest version.