# BoringSSL errors on iOS 11 running on xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm running my framework on xcode 9 on an iOS 11 phone and getting the below errors. Can't find a reference to BoringSSL anywhere in my code, not sure how to solve this. My framework worked previously on ios 10 and xcode 8.

```
[] network_config_register_boringssl_log_debug_updates Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates
[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_npn_data: line 1214 Peer's advertised NPN data is NULL or empty
```

A similar question was asked here, however the solution just hides output.

[Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410572/failed-to-register-for-boringssl-log-debug-updates)

Comment: Possible explanation: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/14418#issuecomment-308850249