# SwiftUI Weather App with OpenWeatherMap API returns "Failed to log metrics" error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, openweathermap

I am attempting to set up a new SwiftUI weather app that uses the OpenWeatherMap Api string "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}" to pass in a city. I set up my contentView, model, and viewModel to return the city name, temp, and weather description, but am still getting the following error when I run the app:

```
2021-11-09 23:26:56.923188-0500 SwftUIMVVMWeatherDemo[13982:634181] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(144) Failed to log metrics
failed
```

My contentView, model, and viewModel are as follows:

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = WeatherViewModel()
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            VStack {
                
                Text(viewModel.name)
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                Text(viewModel.temp)
                    .font(.system(size: 44))
                Text(viewModel.descriptionText)
                    .font(.system(size: 24))

                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Weather MVVM")
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Model

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherModel: Codable {
    let name: String
    let main: CurrentWeather
}

struct CurrentWeather: Codable {
    let temp: Float
    let weather: [WeatherInfo]
}

struct WeatherInfo: Codable {
    let description: String
}
```

ViewModel

```
import Foundation

class WeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var name: String = "-"
    @Published var temp: String = "-"
    @Published var descriptionText: String = "-"
    
    init() {
        fetchWeather()
    }
    
    func fetchWeather() {
                
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=chicago&appid=<myAPIKeyGoesHere>") else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            // get data
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            //convert data to model
            do {
                let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherModel.self, from: data)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {                    
                    self.name = model.name
                    self.temp = "\(model.main.temp)"
                    self.descriptionText = model.main.weather.first?.description ?? "No Description"
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("failed")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

The error message is vague. Any idea what might be wrong? Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: That message your seeing isn't actually related to *your* code -- it's just an OS log. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44410572/560942 However, you may have other issues with your code. The first thingI'd change is to `print(error)` inside your `catch` block instead of just `print("failed")`. Also, you're returning without printing an error in your `guard` statement. I'd probably look into using `URLSession` with `Combine` since you're in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it maybe due to your incorrect model. Try this:

```
struct WeatherModel: Codable {
    let name: String
    let main: CurrentWeather
    let weather: [WeatherInfo]   // <--- here
}

struct CurrentWeather: Codable {
    let temp: Float
    // let weather: [WeatherInfo]  // <--- NOT here
}
```

Also the city is `Chicago`, although it seems to work with `chicago`