# Failed to log metric block invoke 151

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have set up an iOS app with Firebase in SwiftUI and am receiving the following error:

```
2022-10-30 16:15:17.585348+0600 ToDo_List[9356:7163085]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036001] Analytics screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be logged.
2022-10-30 16:15:17.994711+0600 ToDo_List[9356:7163085] 9.6.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.9.6.0 started
2022-10-30 16:15:17.995903+0600 ToDo_List[9356:7162996] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 9.6.0
2022-10-30 16:15:18.111502+0600 ToDo_List[9356:7163085] 9.6.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2022-10-30 16:15:18.179108+0600 ToDo_List[9356:7163087] 9.6.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2022-10-30 16:15:18.187070+0600 ToDo_List[9356:7163101] 9.6.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2022-10-30 16:15:48.458920+0600 ToDo_List[9356:7163613] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
```

I have try to add login and signup with Firebase.

Comment: While posting an error can be helpful, it's equally as important to post the code that caused the error. Please  perform troubleshooting by stepping through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected. Then update the question with that code. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Did you encounter any issues with the product you're using when this warning appeared?

Might be just debug information, during API call.

- If you are creating a separate instance to download your json data through `Data(contentsOf: url)`, try using `URLSession dataTask(with: URL)` to download it, in the same instance.

If there are no issues with the product, you might wanna disable log-debug-updates for boring-ssl. Heres a neat solution: [Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410572/failed-to-register-for-boringssl-log-debug-updates)