# Hide unwanted Logs printing - in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, warnings, xcode9

I already set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to disable, but after migrating to Xcode 9 there was some unwanted logs printing like the below.

Edit: I already referred [Hide strange unwanted Xcode logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-logs), but doesn't work for me in Xcode 9.

> =================================================================
>   Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotifications]
>   PID: 1303, TID: 27861, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.usernotifications.UNUserNotificationServiceConnection.call-out, QoS: 0
>   Backtrace:
>   4   N-Gal                               0x000000010b058211 _T05N_Gal11AppDelegateC29registerForRemoteNotificationyyFySb_s5Error_pSgtcfU_ + 193
>   5   N-Gal                               0x000000010b0574d3 _T0Sbs5Error_pSgIxyx_SbSo7NSErrorCSgIyByy_TR + 115
>   6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111a4c3f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
>   7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111a4d43c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>   8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111a5595b _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1162
>   9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111a562df _dispatch_queue_invoke + 336
>   10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111a5207d _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 733
>   11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111a591f9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
>   12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111a58e97 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
>   13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000111f141ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
>   14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000111f13c4d start_wqthread + 13
>   Couldn't register: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
>   Couldn't register: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
>   Couldn't register: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
>   22

Can Anyone help me to hide these logs....? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @VinodKumar, please read my question carefully, i mentioned that,  I already set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to disable, i already referred that link and that doesn't work for me. And im asking this question for Xcode 9.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just a log. It's a warning. `[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotifications]` must be called on the main thread. You should move call of this method to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Done, but still the warning and the log is same.

Comment: if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert]) { (granted, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    
                    //   UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5
                }
            }
}

Answer (score 0):

It's not an unwanted log.
You need to call `registerForRemoteNotifications()` in main thread.

Replace code as below.

```
let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
```