# how can made lldb server launching a new process without attaching to the existed one?

Tags: ios, lldb

I'm using `ios-deploy` to launch ios app automatically, it works fine but only a probem: it won't restart the app if it's already running.

I have studied its source code and learned it's using the `lldb` command to launch the app. the lldb script is (part):

```
def run_command(debugger, command, result, internal_dict):
    device_app = internal_dict['fruitstrap_device_app']
    args = command.split('--',1)
    error = lldb.SBError()
    lldb.target.modules[0].SetPlatformFileSpec(lldb.SBFileSpec(device_app))
    args_arr = []
    if len(args) > 1:
        args_arr = shlex.split(args[1])
    args_arr = args_arr + shlex.split('{args}')

    launchInfo = lldb.SBLaunchInfo(args_arr)
    global listener
    launchInfo.SetListener(listener)

    #This env variable makes NSLog, CFLog and os_log messages get mirrored to stderr
    #https://stackoverflow.com/a/39581193 
    launchInfo.SetEnvironmentEntries(['OS_ACTIVITY_DT_MODE=enable'], True)

    lldb.target.Launch(launchInfo, error)
    lockedstr = ': Locked'
    if lockedstr in str(error):
       print('\\nDevice Locked\\n')
       os._exit(254)
    else:
       print(str(error))
```

the start command:

> (lldb) command source -s 0
>   '/tmp/BB1ED2A3-3A3E-413A-935D-323D7A7533D1/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-6a050aabefc708cb7fc6024c4dd1743080d6e20b'
>   Executing commands in
>   '/tmp/BB1ED2A3-3A3E-413A-935D-323D7A7533D1/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-6a050aabefc708cb7fc6024c4dd1743080d6e20b'.
>   (lldb) platform select remote-ios --sysroot
>   '/Users/wellbye/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/12.0
>   (16A366)/Symbols' Platform: remote-ios Connected: no SDK Path:
>   "/Users/wellbye/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/12.0
>   (16A366)/Symbols"    (lldb) target create
>   "/Users/wellbye/git-repo/j/mj3d/Product/build/ios/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/mj.app" Current executable set to
>   '/Users/wellbye/git-repo/j/mj3d/Product/build/ios/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/mj.app' (arm64).    (lldb) script
>   fruitstrap_device_app="/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1FB0E7E3-6616-4789-8E6F-598C4F5AAC35/mj.app"
>   (lldb) script fruitstrap_connect_url="connect://127.0.0.1:62276"
>   (lldb) target modules search-paths add /usr
>   "/Users/wellbye/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/12.0
>   (16A366)/Symbols/usr" /System
>   "/Users/wellbye/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/12.0
>   (16A366)/Symbols/System"
>   "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1FB0E7E3-6616-4789-8E6F-598C4F5AAC35"
>   "/Users/wellbye/git-repo/j/mj3d/Product/build/ios/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos"
>   "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1FB0E7E3-6616-4789-8E6F-598C4F5AAC35"
>   "/Users/wellbye/git-repo/j/mj3d/Product/build/ios/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos"
>   /Developer "/Users/wellbye/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS
>   DeviceSupport/12.0 (16A366)/Symbols/Developer"    (lldb) command
>   script import
>   "/tmp/BB1ED2A3-3A3E-413A-935D-323D7A7533D1/fruitstrap_6a050aabefc708cb7fc6024c4dd1743080d6e20b.py"
>   (lldb) command script add -f
>   fruitstrap_6a050aabefc708cb7fc6024c4dd1743080d6e20b.connect_command
>   connect    (lldb) command script add -s asynchronous -f
>   fruitstrap_6a050aabefc708cb7fc6024c4dd1743080d6e20b.run_command run
>   (lldb) command script add -s asynchronous -f
>   fruitstrap_6a050aabefc708cb7fc6024c4dd1743080d6e20b.autoexit_command
>   autoexit    (lldb) command script add -s asynchronous -f
>   fruitstrap_6a050aabefc708cb7fc6024c4dd1743080d6e20b.safequit_command
>   safequit    (lldb) connect    (lldb) run

I have searched the lldb's python api reference, but haven't seen anything (args or flags) I could use for my purpose.

so how could we let the lldb server know it should kill the exist process and start a new one?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you are trying to support rerun behavior (i.e. you make a target, launch the process, then use the same target to re-run) or if you just want to kill off some instance of the app that was running - maybe because it was finger-launched on the device or whatever.

In the first case, since you are reusing the SBTarget, you can just check whether your target has a process (call `target.process.IsValid()`) and if does kill it with `target.process.Kill()` before launching.

But if lldb is not responsible for launching the extant copy of the app, then it won't know anything about it, and doesn't really have a way to kill it off.

Comment: I have add the checking and killing code before launching, but after killing, the lldb says:`Process 0 exited with status = 9 (0x00000009) error: the platform is not currently connected` and doesn't launch the new process.

Comment: even the app is not running, `lldb.target.process.IsValid` return true, print the process shows `SBProcess: pid = 0, state = connected, threads = 0, executable = mj`

Comment: An exited process stays around (so you could check the exit status for instance.)  But process.state will be lldb.eStateExited.  You don't need to kill those...

Comment: I don't know anything about how ios-deploy works, however, so I can't help with how you would make a new connection to the device if you really did have to kill off the current process.