# Connection error "Permission denied" using AdMob on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

I am having the following connection error when trying to load an interstitial AdMob ad:

```
[NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: <CTServiceDescriptor 0x281e14840, domain=1, instance=1>
```

The idea here is show an ad everytime a viewcontroller is loaded. The implementation is based on google's [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial). 
For my applicationID have tried both my own and google's test one.

My `AppDelegate.swift` is:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
    GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511")  \\ google's test ID

    return true
}
```

My viecontroller's extension is:

```
extension MenuViewController: GADInterstitialDelegate {
func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")  \\ google's test ID
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}

func showAd() {
    if interstitial.isReady {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else {
        print("Ad wasn't ready")
    }
}
}
```

And my call in `viewdidload`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Ads
    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    showAd()
...
```

My full log is:

```
2019-01-25 19:46:06.192791+0100 TimerApp[9118:2416519] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
2019-01-25 19:46:06.488342+0100 TimerApp[9118:2416370] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-01-25 19:46:06.489723+0100 TimerApp[9118:2416370] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
Ad wasn't ready
2019-01-25 19:46:07.492398+0100 TimerApp[9118:2416505] [NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: <CTServiceDescriptor 0x282ac4ce0, domain=1, instance=1>
2019-01-25 19:46:07.745157+0100 TimerApp[9118:2416370] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port Speaker (type: Speaker)
2019-01-25 19:46:07.755242+0100 TimerApp[9118:2416505] <Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"7df8e261fcfdb632b0663a3e42407e21" ];
2019-01-25 19:46:07.939245+0100 TimerApp[9118:2416540] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process TimerApp
2019-01-25 19:46:07.939302+0100 TimerApp[9118:2416540] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
filterBlacklist =     (
);
filterWhitelist =     (
);
noOverridingAllowed = 1;
restrictWeb = 1;
useContentFilter = 0;
useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2019-01-25 19:46:07.939346+0100 TimerApp[9118:2416540] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2019-01-25 19:46:10.210927+0100 TimerApp[9118:2416370] Warning: Attempt to present <TimerApp.SettingsViewController: 0x104841450>  on <TimerApp.MenuViewController: 0x105023400> which is already presenting <TimerApp.SettingsViewController: 0x10483cb40>
2019-01-25 19:46:11.557808+0100 TimerApp[9118:2416370] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port Speaker (type: Speaker)
```

Comment: Please read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-logs

Comment: This mistake doesn't related with your codes. Its might be Xcode bug. You can ignore it

Comment: Thanks guys. I know why my ads did not show. I was calling showAd() too soon, while the ad hasn't loaded yet. The log messages really threw me off here. I have disabled them with Ajay Saini's link.

Answer (score 0):

I know why my ads did not show. I was calling showAd() too soon, while the ad hasn't loaded yet. The log messages really threw me off here. I have disabled them with Ajay Saini's link.