# Why I get the console warning: [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1 when I load a WKWebView in iOS13.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, ios13

Since I installed the **iOS 13.2 beta**, I have been getting a debug console error message. It happens every time I load a ViewController with a WKWebView object in the storyboard.

Then the following message is shown continuously while the web view is visible
...

```
2019-10-10 12:10:47.867830+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:47.908698+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:47.908814+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:47.934169+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:47.947668+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:47.964375+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:48.193556+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:48.193723+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:48.193941+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:48.194012+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:48.195679+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:48.200432+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:48.207225+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
2019-10-10 12:10:48.207298+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
```

At the moment I close the view I get the following message:

```
2019-10-10 12:32:41.577505+0200 (...)[ProcessSuspension] 0x1051e50b0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
```

Sometimes I get the following message in the middle while the web view is loaded: (I can't say when it happens)

```
2019-10-10 12:33:11.453528+0200 (...) Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2019-10-10 12:33:11.459713+0200 (...) Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service
```

And the if I touch the screen it starts again

```
    2019-10-10 12:10:48.200432+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
    2019-10-10 12:10:48.207225+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1  
    2019-10-10 12:10:48.207298+0200 (...) [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1 
...
```

I have checked that this is happening in all of the view controllers with WKWebViews of my app, so it doesn't seem to be a code error.

This **doesn't crash the app**, but I would like to know why this is happening, and if someone else is having the same issue.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

It's a bug in WebKit (or the underlying OS itself).
And no, it was *not* fixed in 13.[2,3] release.

see:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202173
- https://www.mail-archive.com/webkit-changes@lists.webkit.org/msg146193.html

---

Update:

It's fixed in 13.4 release.

Comment: For workarounds see [Comment in Ionic Issue 17494](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17494#issuecomment-492647992)

Comment: For me I was seeing exactly these symptoms and the removal of the background css resolved it. From the comment previous link I came . across Safari bug that looks to me to be root-cause. Removing the background image css eliminated the blinking, ios crashes and the debug streaming observed in slightly different circumstances.

Answer (score 64):

As in the accepted answer, this is a WebKit bug and it <s>seems that it has been fixed but not released up until the latest iOS release 13.2.2 (at the time of writing this answer)</s> **has been fixed in iOS 13.4**.

As a workaround, however, you can disable/hide the logs temporarily as mentioned in [an answer by @iDevzilla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461256/804376):

1- From Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

2- On your Environment Variables set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` = `disable`

[image]

This will ONLY hide the logs so you can continue developing and testing on iOS. As some indicated, this problem crashes their apps no matter what (for me it is not until now). Also, be careful using this method as it might hide important error messages!

Comment: So does this suggest that the error only fires during runtime via xcode? Or will this error persist in a packaged application bundle installed on users devices?

Comment: For our app it crashes in both variants, no matter if using the packaged app or the one started via Xcode. With iOS 12 it runs fine ...

Comment: Disabling OS_ACTIVITY_MODE also removes the LayoutConstraints logs. Fyi.

Comment: It does hide all NSLogs.

Comment: Strange I still see the "kill()" error log messages after setting this environment variable.

Comment: as a fix, you can also not launch the app, but be careful using this method as it might hide important error messages!

Answer (score 7):

iOS 13.4 has removed this error! Hurray!

Comment: 13.5.1 face same issue

Answer (score 3):

I will pre-admit this is a terrible "answer" but it is a valid observation.  This has something to do with sandboxing.  If you rebuild your app without a sandbox, there are no messages.  If you turn on the sandbox and enable Outgoing Connections which is all I need for my app, every mouse event in the webkit gives me the unhappy message.

If I also include Incoming Connections, just as a test, same messages.

Remove the sandbox (for an internal use only app), no stupid messages.  Perhaps this observation will help someone at Apple track this problem down some more.

Answer (score 3):

**Update as of 28 March 2020**

Finally Apple deployed something, which not only doesn't shows the error in the logs, but actually allows us; developers to compile, run and submit an application.

Especially, if it's you're coming with Cordova/PhoneGap app combined with any HTML5/JavaScript framework/game (Ionic/Phaser) which wants to run on iOS as web wrapper (my personal experience related to this issue) by using WebView. However, not sure if the same issue applied to NativeScript/React Native or native Java/Kotlin/Swift - these don't need a web wrapper to run.

Nevermind, please **update your iPhone/iPad to iOS 13.4** ***and (!!)*** **Xcode to 11.4**. Both of them have been released 3 days ago and can confirm that my Cordova-wrapped app doesn't has the log anymore and doesn't crash.

For historical reasons I'll write a note - the affected iOS versions were: 13.2.X, 13.3.X including its betas. If you're reading this after some time - you need to get rid off those by upgrading to a higher version than 13.3 (recommended) or downgrading to lower version than 13.2 (not recommended). The second option you can use only if Apple for some reason would block you with further updates, e.g. your iPad/iPhone will be really old.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know why this affects it, but hey ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I am using `Firebase` - and here was a line in my Podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
```

After removing that, I no longer got these logs. Strange, but it works I guess if you don't yet need this pod for now.

This may also be an issue for other pods, who knows.

I have that line in my Podfile for a feature I am yet to implement, but can't until I get a full Apple Developer Membership account.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have to use both `iOS 13.4` on your device,  and `Xcode 11.4`, otherwise, you'll still see the logs.