# Ionic iOS 13.2 Bug, App crash - kill() returned unexpected error

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, wkwebview

I think Ionic has a huge bug in iOS. I got the following error messages:

```
2019-11-06 12:09:31.560205+0100 MyApp[6687:1400464] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-06 12:09:31.560562+0100 MyApp[6687:1400464] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-06 12:09:31.660322+0100 MyApp[6687:1400464] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-06 12:09:31.660699+0100 MyApp[6687:1400464] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-06 12:09:31.765716+0100 MyApp[6687:1400464] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-06 12:09:31.767176+0100 MyApp[6687:1400464] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-06 12:09:31.862421+0100 MyApp[6687:1400464] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-06 12:09:31.863232+0100 MyApp[6687:1400464] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-06 12:09:33.680251+0100 MyApp[6687:1400464] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-06 12:09:33.680582+0100 MyApp[6687:1400464] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
```

I can run some Ionic v3 App with the error. But some of them crash directly / doesnt open the view. It shows only a white screen.
I cannot run a new, fresh Ionic v4 App. All v4 Apps crash / show only the splashscreen.

Is here anybody with a solution? It is very annoying to get no information.

Comment: i dont think its just ionic. I think its wkwebview related

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing XCode 11.2 iOS 13.2. However my app seems to run fine. But I get hundreds of these errors anytime I perform any action.

Comment: Interestingly enough if I run this in the iOS Simulator I don't see those errors at all.

Comment: I have the same issue but then if I inspect with Safari and from there reload the document, the app works....

Answer (score 3):

Okay, it is a WKWebView bug.

I created a swift app and load a WKWebView. It doesnt work on ios 13.2
I got the kill() errors. But it works well on my other device with an older version of iOS.

Apple published an iOS 13.3 beta version. Maybe the bug will be fixed. Try to install and test it.

Comment: check this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321114/why-i-get-the-console-warning-process-kill-returned-unexpected-error-1-when