# Process kill() returned unexpected error 1 Xcode 11.2 - iOS 13.2 - Swift 5

Tags: swift5, xcode11, ios13.2

**Text translated by google**

I am using a webview and when I upload the data to the webview it shows me these messages. What should I modify, is it a mistake, can it cause problems for my application?

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit

class BeneficiosViewController: UIViewController , WKNavigationDelegate{

    // MARK: - Declarando Variables
    var webView: WKWebView!

    // MARK: - LOAD
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Beneficios"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes=[NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "carnas", size: 22) as Any]

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.sites.google.com/pageweb")
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)

            webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    }
    // MARK: - Funcion para cargar una web
    override func loadView(){
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "......."{
            print(Float(webView.estimatedProgress))
        }
    }
}
```

Log Detail:

```
2019-11-22 09:02:25.003545-0500 ScharffDev[6600:1264134] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-22 09:02:25.003696-0500 ScharffDev[6600:1264134] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-22 09:02:25.004011-0500 ScharffDev[6600:1264134] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-22 09:02:25.004173-0500 ScharffDev[6600:1264134] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-22 09:02:25.004466-0500 ScharffDev[6600:1264134] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-22 09:02:25.004614-0500 ScharffDev[6600:1264134] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-22 09:02:25.004820-0500 ScharffDev[6600:1264134] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
2019-11-22 09:02:25.004965-0500 ScharffDev[6600:1264134] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
```

[image: Error image]

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321114/why-i-get-the-console-warning-process-kill-returned-unexpected-error-1-when

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I get the console warning: \[Process\] kill() returned unexpected error 1 when I load a WKWebView in iOS13.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321114/why-i-get-the-console-warning-process-kill-returned-unexpected-error-1-when)

Answer (score 3):

Apple has finally fixed this bug. Updating to iOS 13.4 makes the error message disappear.
It was just a bug with the OS (versions 13.2 and 13.3), nothing that could cause the app to crash.