# Why is Xcode 11.2 showing unexpected error and how to debug it?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

After updating Xcode to v11.2, the Xcode console is reporting this error when running my Cordova/Ionic app from Xcode. While there is no noticeable issue while using the app, the error throws incessantly, even up to 20 times per second. I am using about 30 different native plugins. The error:

```
2019-11-23 11:29:02.971454+0200 AppName[446:21528] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1
```

I imagine this error has always been there but only now is being reported by Xcode. I would like to understand:

1. What has changed in Xcode such that this error is being reported, and
2. How to debug the error.

**Update**
This appears to be an iOS bug, see relevant [Github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/471) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321114/why-i-get-the-console-warning-process-kill-returned-unexpected-error-1-when) (thanks, @mikey).

Comment: Are your version is v11.2 or 11.2.1? if it's 11.2 i think you should update to v11.2.1 and try again bcz v11.2 have many bugs like mention [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657087/after-upgrading-to-xcode-11-2-from-xcode-11-1-app-crashes-due-to-uitextlayoutv)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321114/why-i-get-the-console-warning-process-kill-returned-unexpected-error-1-when apparently it's a bug :(

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed when updating your device to iOS 13.4. Here are the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_4_release_notes), though they don't mention the fix. However, the notes attached to the software update on the device explicitly mentioned it.

See [Why I get the console warning: [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1 when I load a WKWebView in iOS13.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321114/why-i-get-the-console-warning-process-kill-returned-unexpected-error-1-when?noredirect=1&lq=1)